# XML::Simple ignoring emdash tag?

Tags: xml, perl, xml-simple

I'm using XML Simple to parse an XML file, the problematic part looks like that:

```
    <textBody>
        <title>
            <titlePart>
                <text>SECTION A <emdash/> HUMAN NECESSITIES</text>
            </titlePart>
        </title>
    </textBody>
    <ipcEntry kind="t" symbol="A01" ipcLevel="C" entryType="K" lang="EN">
        <textBody>
            <title>
                <titlePart>
                    <text>AGRICULTURE</text>
                </titlePart>
            </title>
        </textBody>
    </ipcEntry
```

for some reason XML::Simple completely ignores `<text>SECTION A <emdash/> HUMAN NECESSITIES</text>`
I guess its because the emdash tag, because `<text>AGRICULTURE</text>` is parsed just fine.
I also tried setting the parser by:

```
$XML::Simple::PREFERRED_PARSER = 'XML::Parser';
```

still no go.
Any idea?

Comment: [Why is XML::Simple "discouraged"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33267765/why-is-xmlsimple-discouraged)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Having a tag whose value includes both text and other tags is called "mixed content".  [XML::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?XML::Simple) doesn't handle mixed content (not usefully, anyway).  In XML::Simple's view of the universe, a tag can contain either text or other tags, not both.  That's why it's called "Simple".  To quote [its docs](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?XML::Simple):

> Mixed content (elements which contain both text content and nested elements) will be not be represented in a useful way - element order and significant whitespace will be lost. If you need to work with mixed content, then XML::Simple is not the right tool for your job

You'll have to pick a different XML module.  [XML::LibXML](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?XML::LibXML) and [XML::Twig](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?XML::Twig) are popular choices.

Another possibility would be to get whoever produced the XML to use entities instead of tags to represent characters like a dash.  For example, XML::Simple could handle:

```
<text>SECTION A &#8212; HUMAN NECESSITIES</text>
```

just fine.  ([`&#8212;`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2014/index.htm) is an em dash.)

Comment: Will give XML::Twig a try,seems like a lovely module.

Answer (score 4):

`XML::Simple` is parsing it all but it doesn't handle mixed content that well, from the [fine manual](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-Simple/lib/XML/Simple.pm#WHERE_TO_FROM_HERE?):

> Mixed content (elements which contain both text content and nested elements) will be not
>   be represented in a useful way - element order and significant whitespace will be lost.
>   If you need to work with mixed content, then XML::Simple is not the right tool for your
>   job - check out the next section.

For example, this:

```
use Data::Dumper;
use XML::Simple;
print Dumper(XMLin(qq{
    <textBody>
        <title>
            <titlePart>
                <text>SECTION A <emdash/> HUMAN NECESSITIES</text>
            </titlePart>
        </title>
    </textBody>
}));
```

Yields:

```
$VAR1 = {
    'title' => { 
        'titlePart' => { 
            'text' => { 
                'emdash' => {}, 
                'content' => [ 
                    'SECTION A ', 
                    ' HUMAN NECESSITIES'
                ]
            }
        }   
    }
};
```

So the emdash is there but the mixed content is rather mixed up.

Comment: Well that mixed content doesnt help, in fact, it makes my life harder. Thanks,