# Generate XML with same attribute and element name in XML::Simple

Tags: xml, attributes, element

Need to create a XML with the following format using perl XML::Simple module:

```
<module plugin="test"> 
 <plugin>production</plugin> 
</module>
```

Comment: What's the question? What have you tried and what didn't work?

Answer (score 0):

That's one of the limitations of XML::Simple. It's not possible to have a child element with the same name as an attribute. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/33273488/1030675.