# Store xml tags in Variables in perl

Tags: xml, perl, data-structures

Let's say I have a xml-File structured like this

```
<_StoredUserInformation>
    <UserName>
        <WorkstationName>
            <SessionID>
                 This_Session
            </SessionID>
        </WorkstationName>
    </UserName>
</_StoredUserInformation>
```

And I want to store every value inside the xml Tags in my Variables, e.g. :

```
$UserName = <UserName>
$SessionName = This_Session
etc...
```

I Have tried doing it with `ForceArray` from `XML::Simple`, but I am having problems with sorting the keys afterwards. The `KeyAttr` from `XML::Simple` works appartely not with a Data Structure which is nested that much.

Any other suggestions how to solve this?

Comment: Instead of using `XML::Simple`, use [`XML::LibXML`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/XML-LibXML/LibXML.pod) or [`XML::Twig`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Twig). `XML::Simple` document itself says _The use of this module in new code is discouraged_.

Comment: Show the exact code you have used. Your description is unclear. I am not sure what you are trying to achieve. Also, why do you want to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you solve it by backtracking and rethinking what you're trying to accomplish. `XML::Simple` is a route to painful and annoying code, and there's *simply* no good reason to use it.

The module says 'It is discouraged' for a good reason - see here for an expansion of why:

[Why is XML::Simple "Discouraged"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33267765/why-is-xmlsimple-discouraged)

In something like `XML::Twig` what you are trying to do is relatively easy - I'll illustrate for the sake of giving an answer - but I think it's less necessary if you're not having to do the hacky bodge that `XML::Simple` is imposing on you:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Twig;

my $twig = XML::Twig -> parsefile ('your_file.xml' );

my $session_id = $twig -> get_xpath ('//SessionID',0) -> trimmed_text;
print "Session: $session_id\n";
```

You can use a similar method to put tags into variables if you really want, but I'd suggest you don't actually need to - and what you're doing here is chasing an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

I would therefore suggest - backtrack a bit, explain what you're actually trying to accomplish and then ask another question, as the solution is almost certainly a lot less complicated using [`XML::Twig`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-Twig/Twig.pm) or `XML::LibXML`