# Accessing returned values as an array

Tags: arrays, perl

I have simple XML that I want to read in Perl and make hash containing all read keys.

Consider this code:

```
my $content = $xml->XMLin("filesmap.xml")->{Item};
my %files = map { $_->{Path} => 1 } @$content;
```

This snippet works great when XML file contains many `Item` tags. Then `$content` is a reference to array. But when there is only one `Item` I get an error when dereferencing as array. My assumption is that `$content` is a reference to the scalar, not array.

What is the practice to make sure I get array of values read from XML?

Comment: First: [Don't use XML::Simple](/http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33267765/why-is-xmlsimple-discouraged)  and then it's all nice and easy. Give us an XML Sample, and we'll be able to give you a precise answer.

Comment: Appeared posts already answer my question. In general there is a practice to use `ref $content eq 'ARRAY'` where I need to make sure I get arrays, which is ugly by the way, but in my XML case I can use ForceArray parameter or use another xml lib. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you need is to not use [`XML::Simple`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33267765/why-is-xmlsimple-discouraged) and then it's really trivial. My favourite for fairly straightforward XML samples is [`XML::Twig`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-Twig/Twig.pm)

```
use XML::Twig;
my $twig = XML::Twig -> new -> parsefile ( 'filesmap.xml' ); 

my @files = map { $_ -> trimmed_text } $twig -> get_xpath ( '//Path' );
```

With a more detailed XML sample (and desired result) I'll be able to give you a better answer.

Part of the problem with `XML::Simple` is it tries to turn an XML data structure into perl data structures, and - because hashes are key-values and *unordered* but arrays are ordered, it has to guess. And sometimes it does it wrong, and other times it's inconsistent.

If you want it to be consistent, you can set:

```
my $xml = XMLin( "filesmap.xml", ForceArray => 1, KeyAttr => [], ForceContent => 1 );
```

But really - `XML::Simple` is just a route to pain. Don't use it. If you don't like `XML::Twig`, try `XML::LibXML` instead.

Answer (score 1):

What I would say you need is a **flatten**-ing step.

```
my %files 
    = map { $_->{Path} => 1 } 
      # flatten...
      map { ref() eq 'ARRAY' ? @$_ : $_ } 
      $xml->XMLin("filesmap.xml")->{Item}
    ;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do a check and force the return into an array reference if necessary:

```
my $content = $xml->XMLin("filesmap.xml")->{Item};

$content = ref $content eq 'ARRAY'
    ? $content
    : [$content];
```

Comment: personally, I'd reverse the logic: `ref $content eq 'ARRAY' ? $content : [ $content ]`

Comment: Or y'know, turn on `ForceArray` (or just not use XML::Simple in the first place).