# catch an error in perl

Tags: xml, perl, error-handling

I have to read a huge data base of xml files, using XML::Simple.

```
my $xml = XMLin("${file}", ForceArray => 1, KeyAttr => {});
```

the problem is that some of those xml are corrupted and I would like my program to delete those and keep running. I have not been able to find any way to catch the error comming from XMLin 
`parser error : Start tag expected '<' not found`

Any idea ?

Comment: Look at eval command

Comment: I tried but `if (eval(XMLin("${file}", ForceArray => 1, KeyAttr => {}))` does not work either

Comment: `eval` doesn't return `true/false` if it worked - it returns ... whatever the `eval` would return.You need to trap `$@` for the result of the eval.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off - please don't use `XML::Simple` - it's deeply nasty. [Why is XML::Simple "Discouraged"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33267765/why-is-xmlsimple-discouraged)

To address your point though - broken XML is supposed to be fatal to the parser - it must `die` (by design). The way you handle this in `perl` is wrap it in an `eval` block, and catch `$@` to see if it failed:

```
my $xml = eval { XMLin("${file}", ForceArray => 1, KeyAttr => {}); };
warn $@ if $@;
```

Comment: I didn't know about XML:Simple. Thanks for that

Comment: You aren't the first to be caught out.  It says simple, but it lies.