# How do I create an XML file (in a specific location), containing a given hash?

Tags: xml, perl

So I have a simple hash `key=>{value}` and I need to output this in an XML file (in a specific location).

The output should be like this:

```
<keys> <key1> <value1> </value1> </key1> </keys>
```

I searched on other forums and found that xml::Simple would be a solution, but new in Perl.

Comment: That… doesn't look like XML.

Comment: You can add the imaginary tags which i didn't put

Comment: So what are you asking then? Not how to construct XML (since that part is ‘*imaginary*’)…

Comment: I am asking how to output a hash into an xml file

Comment: You're going to have to provide *a lot* more details. What's the format of the XML? What have you tried? What doesn't work? Please read [**this**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: How many (logical) formats can you have, if i told you that i have a key->value hash

Comment: Infinite! What should the XML look like?! Show us an example!

Comment: <keys>
<key1>
       <value1>    </value1>
</key1>
</keys>

Comment: So nothing like what you've showed us in your question? Put that *in the question*, where it should have been in the first place. And while you do, add your code, and a clear description of how it doesn't work.

Comment: Also - if it's key-value, are you sure you want XML? XML is pretty heavy, and JSON may be more appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XML::Simple is abysmal, especially for generating XML.

---

You said the format should be the following:

```
<keys>
   <key1><value1></value1></key1>
   [...]
</keys>
```

That format doesn't make much sense. The solution below produces XML in the following format:

```
<elements>
   <element><key>key1</key><value>value1</value></element>
   [...]
</elements>
```

Solution:

```
use XML::Writer qw( );

open(my $fh, '>', $qfn)
   or die("Can't create \"$qfn\": $!\n");

my $writer = XML::Writer->new(OUTPUT => $fh);
$writer->xmlDecl();
$writer->startTag("elements");
for my $key (sort keys(%hash)) {
   $writer->startTag("element");
   $writer->dataElement("key", $key);
   $writer->dataElement("value", $hash{$key});
   $writer->endTag("element");
}
$writer->endTag("keys");
$writer->end();
```

---

The following is a terser format:

```
<elements>
   <element key="key1">value1</element>
   [...]
</elements>
```

Solution:

```
use XML::Writer qw( );

open(my $fh, '>', $qfn)
   or die("Can't create \"$qfn\": $!\n");

my $writer = XML::Writer->new(OUTPUT => $fh);
$writer->xmlDecl();
$writer->startTag("elements");
for my $key (sort keys(%hash)) {
   $writer->dataElement("element", $hash{$key}, key => $key);
}
$writer->endTag("keys");
$writer->end();
```

---

Adjust at will.

Comment: Thank youvery much for all the efort. I think I'll go with the second solution.

Answer (score 0):

[ikegami](https://stackoverflow.com/users/589924/ikegami) has covered the hash -> XML case quite nicely. I wish to offer an alternative suggestion - don't, use `JSON` instead. `XML` is quite powerful and complicated, but it's really designed as a document format - think how HTML does things - you have tags, attributes and content.

For a significant number of use cases, you're better off with `JSON` instead - it's a simpler format of hashes and arrays. As a result, it more directly reflects the perl data types.

So you can do:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use JSON;

my %stuff = ( key => "value", 
              another_key => "another_value", 
              some_tags => [ "tag1", "tag2", "tag3" ] ); 

print to_json ( \%stuff, { pretty => 1 } );
```

This gives you:

```
{
   "key" : "value",
   "another_key" : "another_value",
   "some_tags" : [
      "tag1",
      "tag2",
      "tag3"
   ]
}
```

Or collapses it onto one line if you just `to_json ( \%stuff );`:

```
{"another_key":"another_value","key":"value","some_tags":["tag1","tag2","tag3"]}
```

Reading it back in is as simple as:

```
my $json_str =  to_json ( \%stuff );

my $json_object = from_json ( $json_str );
print Dumper \$json_object;
```

If all you need is hashes and arrays (and can do without XML attributes, `xpath`, `XSLT` processing) then this may be a better fit - I suggest it, because you indicate that you want to export a simple hash.

But in either case - [don't use `XML::Simple` - it isn't simple at all.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33267765/why-is-xmlsimple-discouraged)