# Perl: overwrite structure member value

Tags: perl

I am creating $input with this code:
`push(@{$input->{$step}},$time);`, then I save it in an xml file, and at the next compiling, I read it from that file. When i print it, i get the structure bellow.

```
if(-e $file)
my $input =XMLin($file...);
```

`print Dumper $input;`

and I get this structure

```
$VAR1 = {
      'opt' => {
               'step820' => '0',
               'step190' => '0',
               'step124' => '0',
               }
    };
```

for each step with it's time..

```
push(@{$input->{$step}},$time3);


XmlOut($file, $input);
```

If I run the program again, I get this structure:

```
$VAR1 = {
      'opt' => {
               'step820' => '0',
               'step190' => '0',
               'step124' => '0',
               'opt' => {
                        'step820' => '0',
                        'step190' => '0',
                        'step124' => '0'
                        }
         }
```

I just need to overwrite the values of steps(ex:$var1->opt->step820 = 2). How can i do that?

Comment: Start with not using XML::Simple, which is horrible. And post some sample XML with a desired output.

Comment: The XML::Simple is requested.. i know there are other methods

Comment: The desired output would be the same with the first Dumper output.. 
`$VAR1 = {
      'opt' => {
               'step820' => '0',
               'step190' => '0',
               'step124' => '0',
               }
    };
`
what i am trying to do is to acces the values and modify them

Comment: [Why is XML::Simple “Discouraged”?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33267765/why-is-xmlsimple-discouraged)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I just need to overwrite the values of steps(ex:$var1->opt->step820 = 2). How can i do that?

```
$input->{opt}->{step820} = 2;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to say what I always do, whenever someone posts something asking about `XML::Simple` - and that is that `XML::Simple` is deceitful - it isn't simple at all.

[Why is XML::Simple "Discouraged"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33267765/why-is-xmlsimple-discouraged)

So - in your example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

my $xml= XML::Twig->new->parsefile($file);
$xml -> get_xpath('./opt/step820',0)->set_text("2");
$xml -> print;
```

The problem is that `XML::Simple` is only any good for parsing the type of `XML` that you didn't really need XML for in the first place.

For more simple examples - have you considered using `JSON` for serialisation? As it more directly reflects the hash/array structure of native perl data types.

That way you can instead:

```
print {$output_fh} to_json ( $myconfig, {pretty=>1} );
```

And read it back in:

```
my $myconfig = from_json ( do { local $/; <$input_fh> });
```

Something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use JSON; 

my $input; 

my $time = 0; 
foreach my $step ( qw ( step820 step190 step124 ) ) {
    push(@{$input->{$step}},$time);
}

print to_json ( $input, {pretty=>1} );
```

Giving resultant JSON of:

```
{
   "step190" : [
      0
   ],
   "step820" : [
      0
   ],
   "step124" : [
      0
   ]
}
```

Although actually, I'd probably:

```
foreach my $step ( qw ( step820 step190 step124 ) ) {
    $input->{$step} = $time;
}

print to_json ( $input, {pretty=>1} );
```

Which gives;

```
{
   "step190" : 0,
   "step124" : 0,
   "step820" : 0
}
```

JSON uses very similar conventions to `perl` - in that `{}` denote key value pairs (hashes) and `[]` denote arrays.

Comment: The XML::Simple is requested, because it is "basic" (at least that's what I've benn told)

Comment: It is basic, in the same way as trying to light a fire by twiddling a piece of wood. E.g. it's hard work, and prone to failure, and by the way wouldn't you rather use the lighter you've got in your pocket?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the `RootName` option of XMLout. By default, when "XMLout()" generates XML, the root element will be named 'opt'.  This option allows you to specify an alternative name.

Specifying either undef or the empty string for the RootName option will produce XML with no root elements.