# Regular expression to match any number of tags in an XML style document

Tags: regex, xml, perl

I have an XML style document which looks like this:

```
<sentence id="2339">
    <text>I charge it at night and skip taking the cord with me because of the good battery life.</text>
    <aspectTerms>
        <aspectTerm term="cord" polarity="neutral" from="41" to="45"/>
        <aspectTerm term="battery life" polarity="positive" from="74" to="86"/>
    </aspectTerms>
</sentence>
<sentence id="812">
    <text>I bought a HP Pavilion DV4-1222nr laptop and have had so many problems with the computer.</text>
</sentence>
<sentence id="1316">
    <text>The tech guy then said the service center does not do 1-to-1 exchange and I have to direct my concern to the "sales" team, which is the retail shop which I bought my netbook from.</text>
    <aspectTerms>
        <aspectTerm term="service center" polarity="negative" from="27" to="41"/>
        <aspectTerm term="&quot;sales&quot; team" polarity="negative" from="109" to="121"/>
        <aspectTerm term="tech guy" polarity="neutral" from="4" to="12"/>
    </aspectTerms>
</sentence>
```

I want a regular expression which matches 1. the sentence and 2. the polarities of any aspect terms corresponding to the sentence. In other words, a list like this:

```
[
    [
        "I charge it at night and skip taking the cord with me because of the good battery life.",
        "neutral",
        "positive"
    ],
    [
        "I bought a HP Pavilion DV4-1222nr laptop and have had so many problems with the computer."
    ], 
    [
        "The tech guy then said the service center does not do 1-to-1 exchange and I have to direct my concern to the "sales" team, which is the retail shop which I bought my netbook from.",
        "negative",
        "negative",
        "neutral"
    ]
]
```

My problem is that I can only match the last polarity for each sentence's set of aspect terms. I get that this has something to do with repeating my capture group, but no combination of symbols has worked for me so far.

Here is my current regex:

```
/<sentence .*?>.*?<text>(.+?)<\/text>.*?(?:<aspectTerm.*?polarity="(.+?)".*?)*?<\/sentence>/gs
```

(I am using this regex in perl.)

Comment: What are you trying to get of this?

Comment: @Sobrique I believe I give an example in my question - I need a list where each element is a list containing, in the first index, the sentence, and the other indices being the sentiment polarity of each corresponding term. (Or a similar structure)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- [Don't use regex to parse XML.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)
- [Don't use XML::Simple to parse XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33267765/why-is-xmlsimple-discouraged)

Use a parser.  By doing so you get access to `xpath` which is quite a lot like `regex` but "context aware" - it understands the structure of `XML` which means a lot of the problems that regex can cause, just go away again.

Something like this (I'll leave formatting details to one side - but your above looks like you could output a `JSON` arrray and get the desired result)

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

my $twig = XML::Twig -> parse ( \*DATA );

foreach my $sentence ( $twig -> get_xpath('//sentence') ) {
    print "Text:", $sentence -> text,"\n";
    print "Polarities:", join( ",", map { $_ -> att('polarity')} $sentence -> get_xpath('.//aspectTerm/')),"\n";
}

__DATA__
<xml>
<sentence id="2339">
    <text>I charge it at night and skip taking the cord with me because of the good battery life.</text>
    <aspectTerms>
        <aspectTerm term="cord" polarity="neutral" from="41" to="45"/>
        <aspectTerm term="battery life" polarity="positive" from="74" to="86"/>
    </aspectTerms>
</sentence>
<sentence id="812">
    <text>I bought a HP Pavilion DV4-1222nr laptop and have had so many problems with the computer.</text>
</sentence>
<sentence id="1316">
    <text>The tech guy then said the service center does not do 1-to-1 exchange and I have to direct my concern to the "sales" team, which is the retail shop which I bought my netbook from.</text>
    <aspectTerms>
        <aspectTerm term="service center" polarity="negative" from="27" to="41"/>
        <aspectTerm term="&quot;sales&quot; team" polarity="negative" from="109" to="121"/>
        <aspectTerm term="tech guy" polarity="neutral" from="4" to="12"/>
    </aspectTerms>
</sentence>
</xml>
```

This prints:

```
Text:I charge it at night and skip taking the cord with me because of the good battery life.
Polarities:neutral,positive
Text:I bought a HP Pavilion DV4-1222nr laptop and have had so many problems with the computer.
Polarities:
Text:The tech guy then said the service center does not do 1-to-1 exchange and I have to direct my concern to the "sales" team, which is the retail shop which I bought my netbook from.
Polarities:negative,negative,neutral
```

Answer (score 0):

In general it's impossible to parse XML properly using regular expressions, unless the data is very well-behaved, consistent, and uses a simple subset of the XML specification. It's always far better to use a purpose-built XML parser module, such as [`XML::Twig`](http://metacpan.org/module/XML::Twig) or [`XML::LibXML`](http://metacpan.org/module/XML::LibXML). The resulting programs are usually much simpler to read, and especially so once you get used to the [XML DOM specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html)

LibXML has bindings libraries for many languages including Ruby, Python, and PHP as well as Perl, so it is very widely supported

You don't say how your XML data is wrapped. An XML document may have only a single root node, so I've imagined that it's enclosed in `<root> ... </root>` tags

This program uses `XML::LibXML` to process your data and generate the structure that I think you want. It expects the path to the input XML file as a parameter on the command line

I've used [`Data::Dump`](http://metacpan.org/module/Data::Dump) to display the final contents of `@data` which corresponds with the expected output in your question

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use XML::LibXML;

my $dom = XML::LibXML->load_xml(location => shift);

my @data;

for my $sentence ( $dom->findnodes('/root/sentence') ) {

    push @data, [
        $sentence->findvalue('text'),
        map $_->getValue, $sentence->findnodes('aspectTerms/aspectTerm/@polarity')
    ];
}

use Data::Dump;
dd \@data;
```

#### output

```
[
  [
    "I charge it at night and skip taking the cord with me because of the good battery life.",
    "neutral",
    "positive",
  ],
  [
    "I bought a HP Pavilion DV4-1222nr laptop and have had so many problems with the computer.",
  ],
  [
    "The tech guy then said the service center does not do 1-to-1 exchange and I have to direct my concern to the \"sales\" team, which is the retail shop which I bought my netbook from.",
    "negative",
    "negative",
    "neutral",
  ],
]
```