# How to convert XML characters to utf8?

Tags: xml, perl, utf-8

When I dump xml using `Simple::XML` I end up with strings that contain escaped characters such as `\x{e6}`. Here is an example

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Data::Dumper;
use Encode;

$s="sel\x{e6}re";
decode_utf8($s);
print Dumper $s;
```

outputs

```
$VAR1 = 'sel�re';
```

**Question**

How can I get the weird character into UTF-8?

**Update**

Here is the full xml output. http://pastebin.com/Sitm01kh

**Update 2**

As pointed out in the comments, the XML is fine, but the problem comes when I

```
my $ref = XMLin($xml, ForceArray => 1, KeyAttr => { Element => 'Id' });
print Dumper $ref;
```

http://pastebin.com/7KDB50fd

Comment: can you post a piece of source XML?

Comment: Sure. Just added the full xml at http://pastebin.com/Sitm01kh

Comment: I don't see escaped strings or question mark diamonds in the pastebin.

Comment: Good point. I now see that it is `XMLin` that introduces the problem. I have updated OP.

Comment: Have you read "STATUS OF THIS MODULE" in [XML::Simple](http://p3rl.org/XML::Simple)?

Comment: [Why is XML::Simple "discouraged"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33267765/why-is-xmlsimple-discouraged)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use DDP;
use XML::Simple;

my $xml = '<Element Id="496669" ParentId="495555" Name="Klasselærere" ContextName="01005 Advanced Engineering Mathematics 1 E15/Klasselærere" IsArchived="false" SubgroupCount="0" />';

my $result = XMLin($xml);

binmode(STDOUT, ":utf8");
print p($result)
```

produces the following output

```
{
   ContextName     "01005 Advanced Engineering Mathematics 1 E15/Klasselærere",
   Id              496669,
   IsArchived      "false",
   Name            "Klasselærere",
   ParentId        495555,
   SubgroupCount   0
   }
```

Data::Dumper itself works weirdly with unicode. Use Data::Printer to see unicode characters

Answer (score 1):

I guess that your terminal is not able to display the caracter \xe6.

If you are on linux, type 'locale' to see what are the settings of your terminal.

You can try to set the terminal encoding like that :

export LC_ALL=utf-8

Comment: locales influence the settings of your shell, not the terminal. The terminal is usually configured via its menu.

Comment: you're right; I meant the terminal'shell. AFAIK, Data::Dumper works fine with unicode, so it seems to me the problem is more on the shell side.

Comment: to work with Data::Dumper and unicode you should configure Data::Dumper::AutoEncode first,  which makes code quite noisy