# XML:Simple and multilevel

Tags: xml, perl

I'm trying to get the value of "longitude" from the following with XML::Simple.

Could anyone provide a code example?

```
<response>
<feedMessageResponse>
<count>1</count>
<feed>...
<id>02JvgufQqMhyMgAB5Rv7DOgge0LJjSly0</id>
</feed>
<totalCount>1</totalCount>
<activityCount>0</activityCount>
<messages>
<message clientUnixTime="0">
<id>527604536</id>
<messengerId>0-2136339</messengerId>
<messengerName>michael</messengerName>
<unixTime>1458736183</unixTime>
<messageType>TRACK</messageType>
<latitude>35.3825</latitude>
<longitude>-80.92035</longitude>
<modelId>SPOTCONNECT</modelId>
<showCustomMsg>N</showCustomMsg>
<dateTime>2016-03-23T12:29:43+0000</dateTime>
<messageDetail/>
<batteryState>GOOD</batteryState>
<hidden>0</hidden>
</message>
</messages>
</feedMessageResponse>
</response>
```

Comment: As the author of XML::Simple I heartily endorse XML::LibXML as a better choice - even for simple projects.  In fact I wrote [Perl XML::LibXML by Example](http://grantm.github.io/perl-libxml-by-example/) specifically to help people make the move.

Answer (score 5):

I wouldn't suggest using `XML::Simple` at all. It lies. It's not simple. 
See here: [Why is XML::Simple "Discouraged"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33267765/why-is-xmlsimple-discouraged)

Instead:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

print XML::Twig -> parse ( \*DATA) -> get_xpath('//longitude',0) -> text;

__DATA__
<response>
<feedMessageResponse>
<count>1</count>
<feed>...</feed>
<totalCount>1</totalCount>
<activityCount>0</activityCount>
<messages>
<message clientUnixTime="0">
<id>527604536</id>
<messengerId>0-2136339</messengerId>
<messengerName>michael</messengerName>
<unixTime>1458736183</unixTime>
<messageType>TRACK</messageType>
<latitude>35.3825</latitude>
<longitude>-80.92035</longitude>
<modelId>SPOTCONNECT</modelId>
<showCustomMsg>N</showCustomMsg>
<dateTime>2016-03-23T12:29:43+0000</dateTime>
<messageDetail/>
<batteryState>GOOD</batteryState>
<hidden>0</hidden>
</message>
</messages>
</feedMessageResponse>
</response>
```

Output:

```
-80.92035
```

Comment: How would I open an xml file for input and assign longitude as a variable?

Comment: If you read the docs on XML::Twig, you will see there is a `parsefile` method.  Or you can just `parse(<>)`

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation for [XML::Simple](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Simple):

> The use of this module in new code is discouraged. Other modules are
>   available which provide more straightforward and consistent
>   interfaces. In particular, XML::LibXML is highly recommended and
>   XML::Twig is an excellent alternative.
>
> The major problems with this module are the large number of options
>   (some of which have unfortunate defaults) and the arbitrary ways in
>   which these options interact - often producing unexpected results.

But if you want to ignore that warning, you can use XML::Simple like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use XML::Simple;

my $doc = XMLin('data.xml');

say $doc->{feedMessageResponse}{messages}{message}{longitude};
```

Personally, I much prefer XML::LibXML.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use XML::LibXML;

my $parser = XML::LibXML->new();
my $doc = $parser->parse_file('data.xml');

say $doc->findvalue('//longitude');
```

Comment: With the XML::LibXML example above.  How would you specify the second instance of "id"?

Comment: The parameter to `findvalue()` is an [XPath](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/) expression. I think you'll need the `position()` function.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Dave Cross, I find XML::LibXML to be a lot easier.  This is what I would do if your file contained multiple longitude values

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;
use XML::LibXML;

my $file = 'test.xml'; #location of the file or it could be a url as well

my $parser = XML::LibXML->new();
my $tree = $parser->parse_file($file);
my $root = $tree->getDocumentElement;
my @longitude = $root->getElementsByTagName('longitude');

foreach my $res (@longitude) {
    print "Longitude : " . $res->textContent() . "\n";
}
```

This is just a simple example, you can change it to suit your needs