# Perl XML::Simple: SuppressEmpty for xsi:nil-Elements without content?

Tags: xml, perl, xml-simple

I'm struggling with XML::Simple in Perl and nullable Elements.

So this is my example-XML:

```
<MyXml>
    <SomeNumber>123</SomeNumber>
    <EmptyOne/>
    <NullableElement xsi:nil="true"></NullableElement>
</MyXml>
```

If I read this with *XMLin* and *SuppressEmpty => 1* I'll get an empty string for the **EmptyOne**, but a Hash with *xsi:nil="true"* for the **NullableElement**. My questions is, how can I tell the XMLin to ignore the xsi:nil-Content and just give me an empty string or undef? Is this even possible with XML::Simple or should I switch to Lib::XML?

Here some code to see the result:

```
use XML::Simple;
use Data::Dumper;

my $xmlIn = '<MyXml><SomeNumber>123</SomeNumber><EmptyOne/><NullableElement xsi:nil="true"></NullableElement></MyXml>';
my $xmlHash = XMLin($xmlIn, SuppressEmpty => '');

print Dumper($xmlHash);
```

Comment: There's a reason `XML::Simple` is [discouraged](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33267765/why-is-xmlsimple-discouraged). Stick with `XML::Twig` `XML::LibXML`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I found a solution for my problem by myself, but this only works for my specific case, because I don't have any attributes I need. If so, you can change the line

```
my $xmlHash = XMLin($xmlIn, SuppressEmpty => '');
```

to

```
my $xmlHash = XMLin($xmlIn, NoAttr => 1, SuppressEmpty => '');
```

This will cut off all the attributes and return an empty string like a regular empty Element.

As mentioned before, this will only work if you don't need any attributes from the xml. If you do need them, this won't work.

Comment: Have you seen the massive antipathy towards `XML::Simple`? I'm surprised you haven't been flooded with answers that tell you to look at [the module's documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Simple) which says *"You really don't want to use this module in new code"*. Please try [XML::Twig](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Twig) or [XML::LibXML](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::LibXML) and save yourself some tears

Comment: In my typical projects I use XML::LibXML by myself. In this case I just adopted the project from a colleague ;) I was wondering if there are any other solutions to achieve this and as I mentioned in my questions, I'm not forced to use XML::Simple.

Answer (score 0):

In `XML::Twig`:

```
use XML::Twig;
my $xmlIn =
  '<MyXml><SomeNumber>123</SomeNumber><EmptyOne/><NullableElement xsi:nil="true"></NullableElement></MyXml>';

print XML::Twig->parse($xmlIn)->get_xpath( '//NullableElement', 0 )->text, "\n";
```

`XML::Simple`: [Why is XML::Simple "Discouraged"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33267765/why-is-xmlsimple-discouraged)

It just isn't worth using, as it's a road to brittle code.