# How to best reiterate through this perl data structure for desired output ? Is it possible without rebuilding existing one?

Tags: perl, perl-data-structures

Perl beginner here, i have a script which makes api call, collects feedback in xml format, then using XML::Simple, massages data into below data structure, im trying to shoot for the following output:

filename1.req, UserFaulted,123

filename2.req, UserFaulted,321

Data Structure:

```
$VAR1 = {
      'xmlns:i' => 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance',
      'xmlns' => 'http://example.com',
      'UserRequest' => {
                       'i1' => {
                               'Id' => 'e012',
                               'Dependencies' => [
                                                 {}
                                               ],
                               'xmlns:z' => 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/',
                               'IdentityUserNumber' => '123',
                               'Stage' => 'UserFaulted',
                               'StartTimestamp' => '2016-04-29T00:05:11',
                               'HomeFileName' => 'filename1.req',
                               'UseBypass' => 'false'
                             },
                       'i2' => {
                               'Id' => 'e013',
                               'Dependencies' => [
                                                 {}
                                               ],
                               'xmlns:z' => 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/',
                               'IdentityUserNumber' => '321',
                               'Stage' => 'UserFaulted',
                               'StartTimestamp' => '2016-04-19T19:50:18',
                               'HomeFileName' => 'filename2.req',
                               'UseBypass' => 'false'
                             }

                     }
    };
```

Here is what i have so far, at this point im starting to think i shot myself in the foot, but any feedback or suggestions would be greatly appreciated

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Simple qw(:strict);
use Data::Dumper;



my $time = "2016-04-19";

my $api_faultedreqs = `curl -x 111.222.333.444:8080 -U user:pass -H "Accept: application/xml" -H "Content-Type: application/xml" "https://example.com" 2>/dev/null`;



my $xml_fault_reqs = XMLin($api_faultedreqs, KeyAttr => { UserRequest => 'Id' }, ForceArray => [ 'UserRequest', 'Dependencies' ]);
my %xml_fault_reqs = %$xml_fault_reqs;
my %clean_out = ();


print Dumper($xml_fault_reqs);

#print $xml_fault_reqs->{UserRequest}->{i1}->{HomeFileName};

for my $outer_key (keys %xml_fault_reqs){
        next if $outer_key =~/xmlns/;
                for my $req_ids2 (keys %{ $xml_fault_reqs{$outer_key} }){
                        for my $req_data (keys %{ $xml_fault_reqs{$outer_key}{$req_ids2} }){
                                next if $req_data =~/xmlns/ or $req_data =~/Dependencies/ or $req_data =~/UseBypass/ or $req_data =~/EndTimestamp/;
                                #print "$req_data, $xml_fault_reqs{$outer_key}{$req_ids2}{$req_data}\n";
                                print "$xml_fault_reqs{$outer_key}{$req_ids2}{HomeFileName}, $xml_fault_reqs{$outer_key}{$req_ids2}{Stage}\n";
                        }
                }
}
```

XML output as requested:

```
<ArrayOfUserRequest xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://example.com">
<UserRequest xmlns:z="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/" z:Id="i1">
    <Dependencies/>
    <HomeFileName>filename1.req</HomeFileName>
    <IdentityUserNumber>123</IdentityUserNumber>
    <Stage>UserFaulted</Stage>
    <StartTimestamp>2016-04-29T00:05:11</StartTimestamp>
    <UseBypass>false</UseBypass>
</UserRequest>
<UserRequest xmlns:z="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/" z:Id="i2">
    <Dependencies/>
    <HomeFileName>filename2.req</HomeFileName>
    <IdentityUserNumber>321</IdentityUserNumber>
    <Stage>UserFaulted</Stage>
    <StartTimestamp>2016-04-20T15:44:51</StartTimestamp>
<UseBypass>false</UseBypass>
</UserRequest>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow and the Perl tag. Please [edit] your question and show the actual input XML. Since XML::Simple is discouraged (and says so itself), you will likely receive concise answers that do what you want in a lot less code, but with a different XML module. For that, we need the source XML.

Comment: Thanks simbabque, yes i saw that warning in the documentation too, live and learn i guess :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for showing the XML data. It helps a lot

Here's a solution that uses the [`XML::LibXML`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::LibXML) module to parse the data. It's a little more complicated than it could be because your data uses the default namespace with `xmlns="http://example.com"`. That namespace must be defined and used explicitly in an XPath expression, which means you also need to create an XPath context object using the [`XML::LibXML::XPathContext`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::LibXML::XPathContext) module. That allows you to register namespaces and use them in your XPath expressions. Even the default namespace must have a name, so I've called it `nul`, and prefixed every node name with `nul:`

The code is quite simple. It uses `findnodes` to locate all `UserRequest` nodes, and pulls the values of the `HomeFileName`, `Stage`, and `IdentityUserNumber` children from each of them, printing the results with a `printf` call

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature 'say';

use XML::LibXML;

my $dom = XML::LibXML->load_xml(IO => \*DATA);
my $xpc = XML::LibXML::XPathContext->new($dom);
$xpc->registerNs(nul => 'http://example.com');

for my $request ( $xpc->findnodes('/nul:ArrayOfUserRequest/nul:UserRequest') ) {

    printf "%s, %s,%s\n",
            $xpc->findvalue('nul:HomeFileName', $request),
            $xpc->findvalue('nul:Stage', $request),
            $xpc->findvalue('nul:IdentityUserNumber', $request);
}

__DATA__
<ArrayOfUserRequest xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://example.com">
<UserRequest xmlns:z="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/" z:Id="i1">
    <Dependencies/>
    <HomeFileName>filename1.req</HomeFileName>
    <IdentityUserNumber>123</IdentityUserNumber>
    <Stage>UserFaulted</Stage>
    <StartTimestamp>2016-04-29T00:05:11</StartTimestamp>
    <UseBypass>false</UseBypass>
</UserRequest>
<UserRequest xmlns:z="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/" z:Id="i2">
    <Dependencies/>
    <HomeFileName>filename2.req</HomeFileName>
    <IdentityUserNumber>321</IdentityUserNumber>
    <Stage>UserFaulted</Stage>
    <StartTimestamp>2016-04-20T15:44:51</StartTimestamp>
<UseBypass>false</UseBypass>
</UserRequest>
</ArrayOfUserRequest>
```

#### output

```
filename1.req, UserFaulted,123
filename2.req, UserFaulted,321
```

Answer (score 1):

As [simbabque *intimated in his comment*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36941647/how-to-best-reiterate-through-this-perl-data-structure-for-desired-output-is-i#comment61442653_36941647), `XML::Simple` is generally frowned upon for a number of reasons. You may want to read the Stack Overflow question [*Why is XML::Simple "Discouraged"?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33267765/why-is-xmlsimple-discouraged) to understand better why that is

However you immediate problem is how to navigate a fairly ordinary Perl nested data structure, and you will find a useful tutorial on that in [`perldoc perlreftut`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html)

Here's a simple solution to your problem. The items of interest are the values of the  second-level hash that has `UserRequest`, so this program iterates over those and prints the required fields from each of them

The `printf` uses a hash *slice* to access all three fields at once, with keys `HomeFileName`, `Stage`, and `IdentityUserNumber`. The `printf` format displays all three on a single line in the format that you have asked for

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use XML::Simple;

# my $data = XMLin(...);

my $data = {
    'xmlns:i'     => 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance',
    'xmlns'       => 'http://example.com',
    'UserRequest' => {
        'i1' => {
            'Id'                 => 'e012',
            'Dependencies'       => [ {} ],
            'xmlns:z'            => 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/',
            'IdentityUserNumber' => '123',
            'Stage'              => 'UserFaulted',
            'StartTimestamp'     => '2016-04-29T00:05:11',
            'HomeFileName'       => 'filename1.req',
            'UseBypass'          => 'false'
        },
        'i2' => {
            'Id'                 => 'e013',
            'Dependencies'       => [ {} ],
            'xmlns:z'            => 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/',
            'IdentityUserNumber' => '321',
            'Stage'              => 'UserFaulted',
            'StartTimestamp'     => '2016-04-19T19:50:18',
            'HomeFileName'       => 'filename2.req',
            'UseBypass'          => 'false'
        }
    }
};

for my $request ( values %{ $data->{UserRequest} } ) {
    printf "%s, %s,%s\n", @{$request}{qw/ HomeFileName  Stage  IdentityUserNumber  /};
}
```

#### output

```
filename1.req, UserFaulted,123
filename2.req, UserFaulted,321
```

Comment: @simbabque: It's there because the OP has explained that `$data` is actually the result of an `XMLin` call in the real code, rather than a data literal which isn't of much practical use. So it *will* be necessary in the OP's final solution

Comment: With your commented explanation it of course makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're just trying to print the elements `HomeFileName` and `Stage`.

That being so, using something like XML::Twig lets you:

```
use XML::Twig;

my @things = qw ( HomeFileName Stage IdentityUserNumber ); 

my $twig = XML::Twig->parse($api_faultedreqs);

foreach my $user_request ( $twig->get_xpath('//UserRequest') ) {
    print join ",", (map { $user_request -> first_child_text($_) } @things), "\n";
}
```

Comment: thank you for letting me know about this gem (XML::Twig) just used this in another project! Saved so much time!!! Thanks Again :)