# Parsing XML and Displaying contents

Tags: xml, perl

I have XML from this link [`http://sapxi.dfssi.com/parser/book.xml`](http://sapxi.dfssi.com/parser/book.xml)

I want to get values from the first `book` element. Any idea how to parse it in Perl?

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;
use XML::Simple;
use LWP::Simple;

my $parser = new XML::Simple;

my $url = 'http://sapxi.dfssi.com/parser/book.xml';
my $content = get $url or die "Unable to get $url\n";
my $data = $parser->XMLin($content);

print Dumper($data);
print $data->{book}{title}->[0];
```

I always get

> Not a HASH reference at ./xml_parser.pl line 20.

All I want is to print the title `Book 1 title` and the author value.

Output will be like this.

```
Book title: Book 1 title Author: Book 1 author 1, Book 1 author 2
```

Thanks in advance for helping.

it should be print $data->{book}->[0]->{title};

Comment: solve it already hahaha.

Comment: If you have a solution then you should post it as an answer below. Also, *please* don't use `XML::Simple`: [*Why is XML::Simple "Discouraged"?*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33267765/why-is-xmlsimple-discouraged)

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution using [`XML::LibXML`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::LibXML). [`XML::Twig`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Twig) is a good alternative that you may prefer

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use XML::LibXML;

use constant XML_URL => 'http://sapxi.dfssi.com/parser/book.xml';

my $doc = XML::LibXML->load_xml(location => XML_URL);

my ($book_1) = $doc->findnodes('/booklist/book[1]');

my ($title) = $book_1->findnodes('title[1]');
my @authors = $book_1->findnodes('author');

printf "Book title: %s Author: %s\n",
        $title->textContent,
        join(', ', map $_->textContent, @authors);
```

#### output

```
Book title: Book 1 title Author: Book 1 author 1, Book 1 author 2
```