# Script enhancement to delete unnecessary tags of an XML file

Tags: perl

#### Perl code

```perl
use strict; 
use warnings; 

my @array = qw / abc de fghi jklm sdfe kk/;  
my $filter = join '|', @array; 
$filter = qr/$filter/; 

while ( my $record = <DATA> ) { 
    $record =~ s/\<line\>[^<]*?\b$filter\b[^<]*?\<\/line\>//ig; 
    print $record if $record =~ /\S/;
}
```

By using the above code on this XML data

#### XML File

```xml
<data>
<line> sdfe abc adsfefsdf </line>
<line> abc sdffedcfsdf sdf </line> 
<line> sdfe </line><line> abc </line>
<line> sd sfefsdf </line> 
<line> sdfe abc 
<line2> afw sdf a </line2> <line3> kasd ads fewf 2323 </line3>
adsfefsdf </line> 
<line> fhgh kk jj hjsda </line>
<line> abc </line> 
.. 
.. 
.. 
</data>
```

The following output is generated

```xml
<data>
<line> sdfe </line>
<line> sd sfefsdf </line> 
<line> sdfe abc 
<line2> afw sdf a </line2> <line3> kasd ads fewf 2323 </line3>
.. 
.. 
.. 
</data>
```

The expected output is as below

```xml
<data>
<line> sdfe </line>
<line> sd sfefsdf </line> 
.. 
.. 
.. 
</data>
```

#### Condition to be taken into account

The above indicates that the Perl script removes the tags containing elements `abc`, `de`, `fghi`, `jklm`, `sdfe`, or `kk`.

For example, in the two lines of the XML file below

```xml
<line> abc sdffedcfsdf sdf </line> 
<line> sdfe </line> <line> abc </line>
```

the original Perl code works and produces output

```xml
<line> sdfe </line>
```

If additional tags are present within an element, the code is not working. Can the script be enhanced so that additional tags within a tag that contains the desired elements to be removed are deleted.

For example, given the XML data below

```xml
<line> sdfe abc 
<line2> afw sdf a </line2> <line3> kasd ads fewf 2323 </line3>
adsfefsdf </line>
```

Can the Perl code be enhanced such that it would remove the additional tags, and remove the line if the line contains removable elements `abc`, `de`, `fghi`, `jklm`, `sdfe`, or `kk` inclusive of unnecessary additional tags?

Comment: Where you say "the following output is generated", is not correct.  Run the script yourself and you'll see that what you're saying is the output of the given program, is not.

Comment: Your method works but for `<line>` elements with nested elements. The logic of your substitution regex expects no interfering `<` between an opening tag and its matching closing tag. Consider to actually _parse_ xml instead (possibly by using a different tool but perl altogether) - the approach might be too simplistic orlead to overly complicated code; think of xml samples that may contain cdata sections (no easy way to distinguish between verbatim data and syntax elements any more).

Comment: Use a proper XML parser.

Comment: Why do you expect `<line> sdfe </line>` in your output? `sdfe` is part of your filter, isn't it?

Comment: Obligatory: [Parsing XML with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: I'd also recommend you use a proper XML parser. The [Perl XML::LibXML by Example](https://grantm.github.io/perl-libxml-by-example/) tutorial should get you up and running quickly with XML::LibXML.

Comment: Thank you all for your feedback

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The following code handles the case of nested insignificant elements. It still doesn't admit for cdata sections in your xml.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my @array = qw /abc de fghi jklm sdfe kk/;
my $filter = join '|', @array;

#
# The xmlprocessing is not line-oriented, thus the whole content can be read in a single sweep.
#
my $record;
{
    local $/ = undef;
    $record = <DATA>;
}

#
# Repeatedly eliminate inner <link...> elements 
#
while ($record =~ /<line[0-9]>/) {
    $record =~ s#<(line[0-9])>[^<]*</\1>##ig;
}

#
# Filter according to the predefined list
#
$record =~ s/<line>[^<]*\b($filter)\b[^<]*<\/line>//ig;

print $record if $record =~ /\S/;
```

Comment: Thank you collapsar, could you also please suggest the reading material for Perl Module aspirers.

Comment: @MikeFroetscher I pretty much favor official docs ( wrt perl: perldoc.perl.org, module docs on cpan ), standards documents where applicable ( notably the rfcs and w3c material ), and SO for accuracy, detail and overall quality of the information. brian d foy's 'effective perl programming' is an excellent read, too (as are his SO answers!). When it comes to XML processing, I'd recommend XML::LibXML, a veneer of the libxml library - it shines with robustness, api comprehensiveness, and good documentation.

Comment: Can the following script be enhanced to work for different inner tag names, different than line2, line3 .... line9,  if the inner-tag names are kty, pst, mct and so on which do not have anything in common,                                                                     ..............................................................................................................#
# Repeatedly eliminate inner <link...> elements 
#
while ($record =~ /<line[0-9]>/) {
    $record =~ s#<(line[0-9])>[^<]*</\1>##ig;
}

Comment: Sure,just add them to an alternation of tag names: `($record =~ /<(line[0-9]|kty|mct|pst)>/) { $record =~ s#<(line[0-9]|kty|mct|pst)>[^<]*</\1>##ig; }`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a proper XML parser instead of trying to hack it with regular expressions

This program uses the [`XML::Twig`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Twig) module. [`XML::LibXML`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::LibXML) is a good alternative if you prefer

```perl
use strict; 
use warnings; 

use XML::Twig;

my @discard = qw / abc de fghi jklm sdfe kk/;  
my $filter = join '|', @discard; 
$filter = qr/\b(?:$filter)\b/;

my $twig = XML::Twig->new;
$twig->parse(\*DATA);

for my $line ( $twig->findnodes('//line') ) {
    $line->delete if $line->text =~ $filter;
}

$twig->print;

__DATA__
<data>
    <line> sdfe abc adsfefsdf </line>   
    <line> abc sdffedcfsdf sdf </line> 
    <line> sdfe </line>
    <line> abc </line>
    <line> sd sfefsdf </line> 
    <line>
        sdfe abc 
        <line2> afw sdf a </line2>
        <line3> kasd ads fewf 2323 </line3>
        adsfefsdf
    </line> 
    <line> fhgh kk jj hjsda </line>
    <line> abc </line> 
    .. 
    .. 
    .. 
</data>
```

#### output

```xml
<data><line> sd sfefsdf </line> 
    .. 
    .. 
    .. 
</data>
```

Comment: Almost eerily similar to what I was about to post. Although I wasn't sure, because _think_ the element containing `line2`, `line3` subelements gets pruned, because the `text` method gives you text from children too.

Comment: @Sobrique: There are only so many ways of applying `XML::Twig`! And yes, you're right, `text` will include all *descendant* text nodes, not just the children. However the OP don't say what they want either way so I'm happy with this for now. It's only a matter of changing `$line_text` to `$line->text_only` if the strings must appear only in the immediate child text nodes

Comment: Can I use XML::SImple and perform a similar operation. As I am new to modules, how would I move forward !

Comment: @MikeFroetscher:  Moving to `XML::Simple` is a very *backward* step! [*Why is XML::Simple "Discouraged"?*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33267765/why-is-xmlsimple-discouraged)

Comment: Thank you Borodin for the feedback, can XML::SAX be utilized ?

Comment: @MikeFroetscher: You could certainly use [XML::SAX](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::SAX), but the API is very different from the more common modules, and you should read [XML::SAX::Intro](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::SAX::Intro) carefully first. SAX is a *push interface*, and `XML::SAX` requires that you create a separate Perl module that subclasses [XML::SAX::Base](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::SAX::Base) and provides methods for all of the document *events* that you want to handle. You will also find fewer people with SAX expertise to help you if you get stuck

Comment: @MikeFroetscher: Can you explain why you're searching for an XML parser other than the ones I listed in my answer? You have picked a broken and deprecated module and a less popular, more esoteric one. What is it that you're looking for?

Comment: I was browsing through https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::SAX#DESCRIPTION  And was interested to know the difference of the strategies followed in different modules, thank you for your help.

Comment: @MikeFroetscher: Essentially your choice is between modules that have a *Document Object Model* (DOM) API and a SAX-like API. The former will build a static Perl data structure that you may navigate and modify, while the latter—which includes the original `XML::Parser`—will inform you, via callbacks, of the nodes that it encounters while parsing some XML text. Experimenting with all of them would be very educational. `XML::Simple` fails by trying to map an XML document onto a simple nested Perl data structure. The two aren't isomorphic so it fails for anything but the most simple XML documents

Comment: @Borodin, thank you. Using a module makes the life easier as compared with a regex when working with an XML file, where parsing needs to be taken into account.