# Parsing XML data into a different structure

Tags: xml, perl, xml-simple

I have the below XML file and I am trying to parse it

```xml
<Books>
  <book name="first" feed="contentfeed" mode="modes" />
  <book name="first" feed="communityfeed" mode="modes" region="1"/>
  <book name="second" feed="contentfeed" mode="" />
  <book name="second" feed="communityfeed" mode="modes" />
  <book name="second" feed="articlefeed" mode="modes" /> 
</Books>
```

I am using Perl version 5.8 together with [`XML::Simple`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Simple). Below is the code I have written

```perl
    use XML::Simple;

    my $xs = new XML::Simple( KeyAttr => { book => 'name' } , ForceArray => [ 'book','name' ] );
    my $config = $xs->XMLin( <complete path to xml file> );
```

Below is the result (displayed using [`Data::Dumper`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Dumper))

```perl
'book' => {
    'first' => {
        'feed'   => 'communityfeed',
        'mode'   => 'modes',
        'region' => '1'
    },
    'second' => {
        'feed' => 'articlefeed',
        'mode' => 'modes'
    },
}
```

Instead I would like to have the output in the format below

```perl
'book' => {
    'first' => {
        'communityfeed' => { mode => 'modes', region => '1' },
        'contentfeed'   => { mode => 'modes' }
    },
    'second' => {
        'communityfeed' => { mode => 'modes' },
        'contentfeed'   => { mode => '' },
        'articlefeed'   => { mode => 'modes' }
    },
}
```

#### Notes

1. The XML file format cannot be changed as it is the current production version
2. Perl version 5.8 is preferred as this is the version used in the parent script and parsing logic should be merged into that script

Have you encountered this kind of issue before? If so then how can this be tackled?

Comment: `XML::Simple` is anything but "simple" to use. Please avoid it if you possibly can. Take a look at [*Why is XML::Simple "Discouraged"?*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33267765/why-is-xmlsimple-discouraged)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`XML::Simple` is an awkward and frustrating module to use, and I doubt very much if you can persuade it to build the data structure that you require. Almost any other XML parser would be a step forward

Here's a solution using [`XML::Twig`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Twig). You can interrogate the parsed XML data and build whatever data structure you like from it

I've used [`Data::Dump`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Dump) only to display the resulting data

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use XML::Twig;

my $config;

{
    my $twig = XML::Twig->new;
    $twig->parsefile('books.xml');

    for my $book ( $twig->findnodes('/Books/book') ) {

        my $atts = $book->atts;
        my ( $name, $feed ) = delete @{$atts}{qw/ name feed /};

        $config->{book}{$name}{$feed} = $atts;
    }
}

use Data::Dump;
dd $config;
```

#### output

```
{
  book => {
    first  => {
                communityfeed => { mode => "modes", region => 1 },
                contentfeed   => { mode => "modes" },
              },
    second => {
                articlefeed   => { mode => "modes" },
                communityfeed => { mode => "modes" },
                contentfeed   => { mode => "" },
              },
  },
}
```