# Parsing xml in perl produce output in different format than I expect

Tags: xml, perl, parsing

I am very new to perl. I am trying to parse an xml file using perl xml parsing module XML::Simple.
Below is the sample xml I am trying to parse:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="US-ASCII"?>
<book>
    <key>ISBN1</key>
    <str>name1</str>
    <key>ISBN2</key>
    <str>name2</str>
    <key>ISBN3</key>
    <str>name3</str>
    <key>ISBN4</key>
    <str>name4</str>
    <key>ISBN5</key>
    <str>name5</str>
    <key>ISBN6</key>
    <str>name6</str>
</book>
```

Below is perl program I am using to parse and dump the parsed output:

```
my $xml = XML::Simple->new;
my $data = $xml->XMLin($bookMap);
print Dumper($data);
```

And the output is:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'str' => [
                   'name1',
                   'name2',
                   'name3',
                   'name4',
                   'name5',
                   'name6'
                 ],
          'key' => [
                   'ISBN1',
                   'ISBN2',
                   'ISBN3',
                   'ISBN4',
                   'ISBN5',
                   'ISBN6'
                 ]
        };
```

But I need it to be parsed in below format:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'ISBN1' => 'name1',
          'ISBN2' => 'name2',
          'ISBN3' => 'name3',
          'ISBN4' => 'name4',
          'ISBN5' => 'name5',
          'ISBN6' => 'name6',
};
```

It seems my xml is in different format than what perl xml parser expects. Could someone help me find a better approach to get the expected output?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: From http://search.cpan.org/~grantm/XML-Simple-2.22/lib/XML/Simple.pm `You really don't want to use this module in new code. If you ignore this warning and use it anyway, the qw(:strict) mode will save you a little pain.`

Comment: `XML::LibXML` http://search.cpan.org/~shlomif/XML-LibXML-2.0126/LibXML.pod and `XML::Twig` http://search.cpan.org/~mirod/XML-Twig-3.49/Twig.pm are suggested as alternatives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please please please - don't use [`XML::Simple`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33267765/why-is-xmlsimple-discouraged). It's discouraged.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Twig;
use Data::Dumper; 

my $twig = XML::Twig -> new -> parsefile($fuseMap);

my %data; 

my @keys = map { $_ -> text } $twig -> get_xpath('//key'); 
my @strs = map { $_ -> text } $twig -> get_xpath('//str');

@data{@keys} = @strs;

print Dumper \%data;
```

Which outputs:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'ISBN2' => 'name2',
          'ISBN6' => 'name6',
          'ISBN3' => 'name3',
          'ISBN5' => 'name5',
          'ISBN1' => 'name1',
          'ISBN4' => 'name4'
        };
```

Or all compressed without temp vars (which may or may not be an improvement):

```
my %data;
@data{ map { $_->text } $twig->get_xpath('//key') } =
           map { $_->text } $twig->get_xpath('//str');
print Dumper \%data;
```

Although I would suggest your source XML is badly structured - if the 'key' and 'str' are matched, they should be within the same element, because that's what elements are *for*. If you have any control over it, can I suggest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="US-ASCII"?>
<books>
    <book key="ISBN1" name="name1" />
</books>
```

Comment: Thanks Sobrique. It worked. You are right the Xml I am trying to parse is not in a good format. I got equivalent json file which can be parsed in the format I am expecting.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the data into the desired format using an hash slice.

```
my %name_by_isbn;
@name_by_isbn{ @{ $data->{key} } } = @{ $data->{str} };
```