# How to get the text contents of an XML child element based on an attribute of its parent

Tags: perl, xml-parsing

This is my XML data

```
<categories>
    <category id="Id001" name="Abcd">
        <project> ID_1234</project>
        <project> ID_5678</project>
    </category>
    <category id="Id002" name="efgh">
        <project> ID_6756</project>
        <project> ID_4356</project>
    </category>
</categories>
```

I need to get the text contents of each `<project>` element based on the `name` attribute of the containing `<category>` element.

I am using Perl with the [`XML::LibXML`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::LibXML) module.

For example, given category name `Abcd` i should get the list `ID_1234`,  `ID_5678`.

Here is my code

```
my $parser = XML::LibXML->new;

$doc = $parser->parse_file( "/cctest/categories.xml" );

my @nodes = $doc->findnodes( '/categories/category' );

foreach my $cat ( @nodes ) {
    my @catn = $cat->findvalue('@name');
}
```

This gives me the category names in array `@catn`. But how can I get the text values of each project?

Comment: Which parser are you using?

Comment: Hi, i am using XML::LibXML to parse the xml file.

Comment: And what output are you seeking specifically? And what do you have already, code wise?

Comment: Please include the code you've already written and explain where you are struggling. You can [edit] your question with the [edit] link. See [ask] for more information on how to use the site.

Comment: my $parser = XML::LibXML->new;
$doc = $parser->parse_file("/cctest/categories.xml");
my @nodes = $doc->findnodes('/categories/category');
foreach my $cat(@nodes){

Comment: [edit] that into your question. This is not a forum - comments are for clarifications/queries not additional content relevant to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This uses XML::LibXML, which is the library you're already using.

Your `$cat` variable contains an XML element object which you can process with the same `findnodes()` and `findvalue()` methods that you used on the top-level `$doc` object.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
# We use modern Perl here (specifically say())
use 5.010;

use XML::LibXML;

my $doc = XML::LibXML->new->parse_file('categories.xml');

foreach my $cat ($doc->findnodes('//category')) {
  say $cat->findvalue('@name');
  foreach my $proj ($cat->findnodes('project')) {
    say $proj->findvalue('.');
  }
}
```

Comment: @ Dave Cross: Thanks a lot. Even this provided code helped  me to meet my requirement.

Answer (score 3):

You haven't shown what you've tried so far, or what your desired output is so I've made a guess at what you're looking for.

With `XML::Twig` you could do something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

my $twig = XML::Twig -> parse ( \*DATA );

foreach my $project ( $twig -> findnodes ( '//project' ) ) { 
    print join ",",  (map { $project -> parent -> att($_) } qw ( id name )), $project -> text,"\n"; 
}

__DATA__
<categories>
<category id="Id001" name="Abcd">
   <project> ID_1234</project>
   <project> ID_5678</project>
</category>
<category id="Id002" name="efgh">
   <project> ID_6756</project>
   <project> ID_4356</project>
</category>
</categories>
```

Which produces:

```
Id001,Abcd, ID_1234,
Id001,Abcd, ID_5678,
Id002,efgh, ID_6756,
Id002,efgh, ID_4356,
```

It does this by using `findnodes` to locate any element 'project'.

Then extract the 'id' and 'name' attributes from the parent (the category), and print that - along with the text in this particular element.

`xpath` is a powerful tool for selecting data from `XML`, and with a more focussed question, we can give more specific answers.

So if you were seeking all the projects 'beneath' category "Abcd" you could:

```
foreach my $project ( $twig -> findnodes ( './category[@name="Abcd"]/project' ) ) { 
    print $project -> text,"\n";
}
```

Comment: Hi , i Tried using XML::Twig and it worked. Thanks for all your help :)

Answer (score -1):

You can try with `XML::Simple`

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Simple;
use Data::Dumper

my $XML_file  = 'your XML file';
my $XML_data;
#Get data from your XML file
open(my $IN, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $XML_file) or die "cannot open file $XML_file";
{
   local $/;
   $XML_data = <$IN>;
}
close($IN);
#Store XML data as hash reference
my $xmlSimple = XML::Simple->new(KeepRoot   => 1);
my $hash_ref = $xmlSimple->XMLin($XML_data);
print Dumper $hash_ref;
```

The hash reference will be as below:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'categories' => {
                          'category' => {
                                        'efgh' => {
                                                  'id' => 'Id002',
                                                  'project' => [
                                                               ' ID_6756',
                                                               ' ID_4356'
                                                             ]
                                                },
                                        'Abcd' => {
                                                  'id' => 'Id001',
                                                  'project' => [
                                                               ' ID_1234',
                                                               ' ID_5678'
                                                             ]
                                                }
                                      }
                        }
        };
```

Now to get data which you want:

```
foreach(@{$hash_ref->{'categories'}->{'category'}->{'Abcd'}->{'project'}}){
  print "$_\n";
}
```

The result is:

```
ID_1234
ID_5678
```

Comment: You _could_ but [xml simple is "discouraged"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33267765/why-is-xmlsimple-discouraged)

Comment: Downvoted for a) recommending XML::Simple and b) using indirect object notation (`new XML::Simple`).