# How to perl convert xml (name with pattern) to json?

Tags: perl

The next convert test.xml to json:

```
perl -MJSON::Any -MXML::Simple -le'print JSON::Any->new()->objToJson(XMLin("/tmp/test.xml "))'
```

but I need convert any xml (example test-1.xml test-2.xml test-3.xml test-4.xml etc) with pattern name /tmp/test-*.xml, but if I use:

```
perl -MJSON::Any -MXML::Simple -le'print JSON::Any->new()->objToJson(XMLin("/tmp/test-*.xml "))'
```

I have the next messages:

> File does not exist: /tmp/test-*.xml  at -e line 1

How I do it?

Comment: It's maybe because `/tmp/test-*.xml` is not an existant file! Did you try this with `/tmp/test-1.xml` ?

Answer (score 3):

There's problems with what you're trying to do:

1. `XML::Simple` isn't simple. It's *for* simple XML. It'll mangle your XML and give inconsistent results. See: [Why is XML::Simple "Discouraged"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33267765/why-is-xmlsimple-discouraged)
2. `XML` is fundamentally more complicated than `JSON`, so there's no linear transformation. You need to figure out what'd you'd do with attributes and duplicate elements for a start.
3. `File does not exist: /tmp/test-*.xml at -e line 1` - means the file doesn't exist. So you're not going to get very far. But `XMLin` doesn't accept wildcards. You'll have to process one file at a time.

The first two points are solvable, provided you accept that this cannot be a generic solution - to give a moderately general solution, we'll need an example of your source XML. But it won't be a one liner.

Comment: isn't simple :). I'll amend.

Comment: Have you ever run a phrase through an online translator and back again? And had it come out nonsense? That's what you're trying to do here. To solve your problem, you need to think about what your problem _actually is_. What needs to be in your output JSON, and what input do you need to process to get it. And then write a solution to _that_ problem, rather than a generic 'XML-to-JSON' converter, which cannot ever work.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be asking how to find files matching a file glob.

You could use

```
my @qfns = glob("/tmp/test-*.xml");
```

If you just want the first matching file, use

```
my ($qfn) = glob("/tmp/test-*.xml");
```

Do not use the following since `glob` acts an iterator in scalar context.

```
my $qfn = glob("/tmp/test-*.xml");  # XXX
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this using `glob` and `map` functions.

```
perl -MJSON::Any -MXML::Simple -le'local $,="\n"; print map { JSON::Any->new()->objToJson(XMLin($_)) } glob "/path/to/my/test*.xml"'
```