# XMLin removes the CDATA

Tags: xml, perl

I am reading an XML file with XML::Simple ( XMLin), doing some substitute operations in some of it's attributes and then XMLOut it in another file. What I noticed is that some of the attributes contained `CDATA` before and after XMLOut they don't anymore.

Input example:
`<name><![CDATA[some text here]]></name>`

Output : `<name>some text here</name>`

Is there an option to keep the CDATA attr? ( I know what CDATA stands for and why it's used)

Comment: Obligatory link: [Why is XML::Simple "Discouraged"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33267765/why-is-xmlsimple-discouraged)

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot I understand their points, but I'd still like to keep it `Simple`. I have used it a lot in a very large area and it didn't dissapoint me so far.

Comment: It is not simple when even the author himself is [recommending](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Simple#STATUS-OF-THIS-MODULE) not to use it. Who knows, you may be running into one of the unknown side-effects they speak of.

Comment: @Adrian: If you *"know what CDATA stands for and why it's used"* then you will know that the plain and CDATA representation of the string are equivalent. No application that handles XML properly will care which is used. `XML::Simple` is *naïve* rather than being simple to use, and you are strongly recommended to avoid it. *"it didn't dissapoint me so far"* Perhaps it just did?

Comment: See [Preserving CDATA Tags When Saving XML](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=701522) on PerlMonks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is XML::Simple "Discouraged"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33267765/why-is-xmlsimple-discouraged)

Comment: Re "*but I'd still like to keep it `Simple`*", It's the most complex parser to use. It's particularly awful at outputting XML. That said, the two XML documents you posted are 100% equivalent.

Comment: As the author of XML::Simple you might think I'm here to defend the module - I'm not. Also, I can confirm it cannot do what you're asking with respect to CDATA sections. I personally use XML::LibXML and find it both simpler and more consistent. I have written a [tutorial on XML::LibXML](http://grantm.github.io/perl-libxml-by-example/) to supplement the reference documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that the text was provided via a CDATA section is lost during parsing. Furthermore, there XML::Simple never produces CDATA sections.

Note that the two XML documents you presented are 100% equivalent. But if you absolutely want to preserve the CDATA sections, I recommend switching to [XML::LibXML](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?XML::LibXML::Parser)<sup>[1]</sup>.

```
$ perl -MXML::LibXML -e'
   my $xml = "<name><![CDATA[some text here]]></name>";
   XML::LibXML->new->parse_string($xml)->toFH(\*STDOUT);
'
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<name><![CDATA[some text here]]></name>
```

The conversion should be relatively simple since both XML::Simple and XML::LibXML provide functionally similar interfaces. For example,

- `my $val = $node->{attr};` ⇒ `my $val = $node->getAttribute('attr')`
- `$node->{attr} = $val;` ⇒ `$node->setAttribute('attr', $val)`
- `for (@$node)` ⇒ `for ($node->getChildren())`

---

1. I recommend switching no matter what. It'll make your life so much [simpler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33273488/589924)!

Answer (score 1):

Look, I know you say in the comments, you want to keep it simple, by using `XML::Simple`. But that's a misnomer. `XML::Simple` isn't - it's actually quite complicated. It's *for* "simple" XML.

And it's ["discouraged"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33267765/why-is-xmlsimple-discouraged) (and even the [module info](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Simple#STATUS-OF-THIS-MODULE) says that) and you have a read through, you'll see why.

But some truly excellent alternatives exist. I'd suggest taking a look at *either* [`XML::Twig`](http://search.cpan.org/~mirod/XML-Twig-3.49/Twig.pm) - which has a lower learning curve - or [`XML::LibXML`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-LibXML/LibXML.pod) which is more fully featured. If you give us some example XML, and what you've tried so far - we can give you an example that'll do what you want. It'll likely be *simpler* than what you've done so far, too.