# Listing all the child nodes of document element

Tags: xml, perl, perl-module

I have a very huge XML file and i want to list down all the child nodes for document element.
I am using the below code which is working fine but it is taking very long time to process the file and also it is getting data from the document element which is not required:

```
use XML::Simple;
my $xml = XML::Simple->new();
my $d = $xml->XMLin("sample.xml");
my @arr = keys %$d;
print "@arr\n";
```

Example XML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-15"?>
<document version="1.0" createdAt="2017-03-31T11:41:34">
   <TITLE>Computer Parts</TITLE>
   <PART001>
      <ITEM>Motherboard</ITEM>
      <MANUFACTURER>ASUS</MANUFACTURER>
      <MODEL>P3B-F</MODEL>
      <COST> 123.00</COST>
   </PART001>
   <PART002>
      <ITEM>Video Card</ITEM>
      <MANUFACTURER>ATI</MANUFACTURER>
      <MODEL>All-in-Wonder Pro</MODEL>
      <COST> 160.00</COST>
   </PART002>
   <PART003>
      <ITEM>Sound Card</ITEM>
      <MANUFACTURER>Creative Labs</MANUFACTURER>
      <MODEL>Sound Blaster Live</MODEL>
      <COST> 80.00</COST>
   </PART003>
   <PART004>
      <ITEM>14 inch Monitor</ITEM>
      <MANUFACTURER>LG Electronics</MANUFACTURER>
      <MODEL> 995E</MODEL>
      <COST> 290.00</COST>
   </PART004>
</document>
```

Expected Output:
TITLE,
PART001,
PART002,
PART003,
PART004

Can anyone please suggest a faster and better way to get the required output?

Comment: [Why is XML::Simple "discouraged"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33267765/why-is-xmlsimple-discouraged)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By using [XML::LibXML](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/XML-LibXML/LibXML.pod) and `XPath`.

```
use 5.014;
use warnings;
use XML::LibXML;

my $file = 'xml';
my $dom = XML::LibXML->load_xml(location => $file);

for my $child ($dom->findnodes( q{//document/*} )) {
    say $child->nodeName();
}
```

output

```
TITLE
PART001
PART002
PART003
PART004
```

or just for the case, if you need only the `PART`s

```
for my $part ($dom->findnodes( q{//*[contains(name(),'PART')]} )) {
    say $part->nodeName();
}
```

output

```
PART001
PART002
PART003
PART004
```

**EDIT:** Using the pull parser (doesn't loads the whole xml into memory):

```
use 5.014;
use warnings;
use XML::LibXML::Reader qw(XML_READER_TYPE_ELEMENT);

my $file="xml";    
my $reader = XML::LibXML::Reader->new(location => $file) or die "problem $!";

while($reader->read()) {
        if( $reader->depth == 1 && $reader->nodeType == XML_READER_TYPE_ELEMENT ) {
                say $reader->name;
        }
}

TITLE
PART001
PART002
PART003
PART004
```

**EDIT2**

```
use 5.014;
use warnings;

use XML::LibXML::Reader qw(XML_READER_TYPE_ELEMENT);
my $file="xml";

my $reader = XML::LibXML::Reader->new(location => $file) or die "problem $!";
my $indoc;
while($reader->read()) {
        # sets the flag in youre inside the <document>
        if( $reader->name eq 'document' ) {
                $indoc = $reader->nodeType == XML_READER_TYPE_ELEMENT ? 1 : 0;
        }
        # all nodes with level 1 if they're inside of the <document>
        if( $indoc &&  $reader->depth == 1 && $reader->nodeType == XML_READER_TYPE_ELEMENT ) {
                say $reader->name;
        }
}
```

Comment: `document` is the root element, so `q{//document/*}` should be `q{/document/*}`,

Answer (score 5):

You can use `XML::Twig` which, according to its [documentation](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-Twig/Twig.pm), is a *perl module for processing huge XML documents in tree mode.*

Here's an example fitting your use case:

```
use feature qw(say);
use XML::Twig;

XML::Twig->new(twig_handlers => {
    'document/*' => sub {
        say $_->name; # print out the element name
        $_->purge; # remove the entire element from memory
    }   
})->parsefile('sample.xml');
```

When used with your sample document, this prints out:

```
TITLE
PART001
PART002
PART003
PART004
```

Using a streaming parser might be even faster.

Comment: This one will work best, because it's stream parsing, not loading the whole XML into RAM.

Comment: Just fun.. You probably want change the `//` comments to`#` :)

Comment: @jm666 Too much Java and JavaScript these days :)

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen I executed the code given above and i got the below error:
encmap iso-8859-15.enc:
No such file or directory
 at /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/XML/Parser.pm line 187
 at test4.pl line 35
 at test4.pl line 35

Comment: yes... I tried the below code given by @jm666 with the same XML and it worked using XML::LibXML::Reader.

Comment: If you don't have euro signs in your data you can replace `encoding="ISO-8859-15"` in the XML declaration with `encoding="ISO-8859-1"` and it should work.