# Can't locate XML/Simple.pm

Tags: perl

`perl -e 'use XML::Simple"`

And get error "Can't locate XML/Simple.pm"

Then I installed  XML:: Simple or Xml::Simple using

`sudo perl -MCPAN -e 'install XML::Simple'`

I also did this

`sudo apt-get install libxml-simple-perl`

still I have same error

> Can't locate XML/Simple.pm in @INC (you may need to install the XML::Simple module) (@INC contains: /home/avrajit/anaconda3/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.22.2/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /home/avrajit/anaconda3/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.22.2 /home/avrajit/anaconda3/lib/perl5/5.22.2/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /home/avrajit/anaconda3/lib/perl5/5.22.2 .) at -e line 1.
>   BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at -e line 1

I did this also 
`apt-cache search XML::Simple`

and output below

> libxml-simple-perl - Perl module for reading and writing XML
>   libdata-validate-struct-perl - module to validate recursive hash structures
>   libdns-zoneparse-perl - Perl extension for parsing and manipulating DNS Zone Files
>   libgtk2-gladexml-simple-perl - clean object-oriented perl interface to Gtk2::GladeXML
>   libtemplate-plugin-xml-perl - XML plugins for the Template Toolkit
>   libtest-xml-simple-perl - Perl testing framework for XML data
>   libxml-hash-lx-perl - module to convert hash to xml and vice versa using LibXML
>   libxml-libxml-simple-perl - Perl module that uses the XML::LibXML parser for XML structures
>   libxml-opml-simplegen-perl - module for creating OPML using XML::Simple
>   libxml-simpleobject-enhanced-perl - Perl module which enhances libxml-simpleobject-perl
>   libxml-simpleobject-libxml-perl - Simple oo representation of an XML::LibXML DOM object
>   libxml-simpleobject-perl - Objectoriented Perl interface to a parsed XML::Parser tree
>   libxml-struct-perl - represent XML as data structure preserving element order
>   libxml-structured-perl - module to convert XML data into a predefined Perl data structure and back
>   ruby-xml-simple - Simple Ruby API for reading and writing XML

what to do now?

Comment: How did you install Perl?

Comment: `apt-cache install libxml-simple-perl` or `apt-get install libxml-simple-perl`, I can't remember which. Only one will work, so whichever works.

Answer (score 3):

If you read error message, it lists directories that are searched for modules:

- `/home/avrajit/anaconda3/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.22.2/x86_64-linux-thread-multi`
- `/home/avrajit/anaconda3/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.22.2`
- `/home/avrajit/anaconda3/lib/perl5/5.22.2/x86_64-linux-thread-multi`
- `/home/avrajit/anaconda3/lib/perl5/5.22.2`
- `.`

None of those directories are standard paths, so I assume that you have two Perl installations, and you have installed `XML::Simple` in one installation, whereas running `perl -e 'use XML::Simple"` invokes the second one. You can check that by running `which perl`.

---

BTW. [`XML::Simple` is bad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33267765/why-is-xmlsimple-discouraged). Use [`XML::LibXML`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::LibXML) or [`XML::Twig`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Twig) instead.

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply. I understand your point working on it.