# XML::Simple convert xml to perl hash warning "non-unique value"

Tags: xml, perl, xml-simple

I have a well formed XML that I'm trying to convert to a hash with perl module XML::Simple. There are some section in this file which cannot be parsed correctly. Is there any way (or a workaround) to get the xml parsed correctly and get the desired result?

```
D:\tmp>perl parse_dns2.pl dns_problem_public.xml
Warning: <dns_entry> element has non-unique value in 'domain' key attribute: 
0 at parse_dns2.pl line 9.
Warning: <dns_entry> element has non-unique value in 'domain' key attribute: 
example.com at parse_dns2.pl line 9.
Warning: <dns_entry> element has non-unique value in 'domain' key attribute: 
test.com at parse_dns2.pl line 9.
$VAR1 = {
  'dns_timeout' => '20',
  'local_dns' => {
    'dns_entry' => {
      '0' => {
        'content' => '192.168.120.32'
      },
      'domain.example.com' => {
        'content' => '172.16.113.13'
      },
      'example.com' => {
        'content' => '172.16.113.13'
      },
      'test.com' => {
        'content' => '172.17.0.113'
      }
    }
  }
};
```

My code is strightforward:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use diagnostics;
use XML::Simple;
use Data::Dumper;

my $ref = XMLin(
    $ARGV[0],
    ForceArray => ['dns_entry'],
    KeyAttr    => { 'dns_entry' => 'priority' },
    KeyAttr    => { 'dns_entry' => 'domain' },
    ForceContent => 0
);

print Dumper $ref;
```

The xml file (the relevant section) contain attributes which I need to use as a key:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE config SYSTEM "config.dtd"> 
<dns>
    <local_dns>
        <dns_entry priority="0">192.168.120.31</dns_entry>
        <dns_entry priority="0">192.168.120.32</dns_entry>
        <dns_entry domain="example.com">172.16.103.20</dns_entry>
        <dns_entry domain="example.com">172.16.113.13</dns_entry>
        <dns_entry domain="test.com">172.17.0.111</dns_entry>
        <dns_entry domain="test.com">172.17.0.113</dns_entry>
        <dns_entry domain="domain.example.com">172.16.103.20</dns_entry>
        <dns_entry domain="domain.example.com">172.16.113.13</dns_entry>
    </local_dns>
    <dns_timeout>20</dns_timeout>
</dns>
```

The first problem that XML::Simple cannot accept similar elements with the same attributes (although different values). And the second problem is that I can use only *one* attribute as a key attribute in the same XML block.

Desired result:

```
$VAR1 = {
  'local_dns' => {
    'dns_entry' => {
      'domain' => {
        'domain.example.com' => {
          'content' => [
            '172.16.113.20',
            '172.16.113.13'
          ]
        },
        'example.com' => {
          'content' => [
            '172.16.113.20',
            '172.16.113.13'
          ]
        },
        'test.com' => {
          'content' => [
            '172.17.0.111',
            '172.17.0.111'
          ]
        }
      },
      'priority' => {
        '0' => {
          'content' => [
            '192.168.120.31',
            '192.168.120.32'
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  'dns_timeout' => '20'
};
```

Comment: Re "*Is there any way (or a workaround) to get the xml parsed correctly and get the desired result?*", You didn't specify what the desired result is.

Comment: @ikegami: thank you, I've added a section with the desired results. Basically a hash with all information included so any element can be addressed using a hash expression.

Comment: Are you sure that's what you want as a result? I mean, if you use `findnodes` you can address any element using an `xpath` expression instead, and you don't have to faff around with mangling your XML. If you want to re-[ask] your question, and frame it around the higher level problem, I'm sure we can supply you with even better answers.

Comment: @Sobrique: I'll use libxml with findnodes for some sections of my xml file. The problem with libxml that I don't know in advance the structure of the xml file and need "walk" through it instead.

Comment: My point is that you probably _don't_ need to know the structure of the file - just what you're looking for. And if you really need to iterate that, you can. But you probably don't need to do that either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nodes can;'t have multiple contents, so some transformation is needed.

You should take this opportunity to avoid using the [most complicated](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33267765/589924) of the XML parsers out there. It's so hard to use its own documentation advises against using it.

Here's an XML::LibXML solution:

```
use XML::LibXML qw( );

my $doc = XML::LibXML->new->parse_file('dns.xml');

my %data;
{
   $data{dns_timeout} = $doc->findvalue('/dns/dns_timeout/text()');

   for my $dns_entry_node ($doc->findnodes('/dns/local_dns/dns_entry')) {
      my $addr = $dns_entry_node->textContent();

      if (defined( my $priority = $dns_entry_node->getAttribute('priority') )) {
         push @{ $data{local_dns}{dns_entry}{priority}{$priority} }, $addr;
      }

      if (defined( my $domain = $dns_entry_node->getAttribute('domain') )) {
         push @{ $data{local_dns}{dns_entry}{domain}{$domain} }, $addr;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: agree, but XML::Simple the only way to parse a xml file with unknown structure, by creating a hash and "walking" through it. I think I have to combine both XML::Simple and LibXML ways in my script. Thank you anyway for a clarifying that XML::Simple is a dead end in my situation :-)

Comment: No, it's not. All XML parsers can handle unknown structure and 'walk' it, just the way you want. E.g. `XML::LibXML` does `childNodes` and `XML::Twig` does `children`. Of course, if you don't actually _want_ to walk the `XML` at all, but instead find a particular key/value somewhere in the  structure, that's where you can use `findnodes` and have a _much_ simpler_ answer.