# using file handle returned by select

Tags: perl

I am pulling out my hair on using the file handle returned by select.

The documentation about select reads:

> - **select**
>     Returns the currently selected filehandle.

I have a piece of code, that prints some data and usually is executed without any re-direction. But there is one use case, where select is used to re-direct the print output to a file.

In this piece of code, I need to use the current selected file handle. I tried the following code fragment:

```
my $fh = select;
print $fh "test\n";
```

I wrote a short test program to demonstrate my problem:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

sub test
{
  my $fh=select;
  print $fh "@_\n";
}

my $oldfh;

# this works :-)
open my $test1, "> test1.txt";
$oldfh = select $test1;
test("test1");
close select $oldfh if defined $oldfh;

#this doesn't work. :-(
# Can't use string ("main::TEST2") as a symbol ref while "strict refs" in use
open TEST2,">test2.txt";
$oldfh = select TEST2;
test("test2");
close select $oldfh if defined $oldfh;

#this doesn't work, too. :-(
# gives Can't use string ("main::STDOUT") as a symbol ref while "strict refs" in use at
test("test");
```

It seems, that select is not returning a reference to the file handle but a string containing the name of the file handle.

What do I have to do to always get a usable file handle from select's return value?

P.S. I need to pass this file handle as OutputFile to XML::Simple's XMLout().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use

```
print XMLout(...);
```

---

> *It seems, that select is not returning a reference to the file handle but a string containing the name of the file handle.*

It can indeed return a plain ordinary string.

```
>perl -MDevel::Peek -E"Dump(select())"
SV = PV(0x6cbe38) at 0x260e850
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (PADTMP,POK,pPOK)
  PV = 0x261ce48 "main::STDOUT"\0
  CUR = 12
  LEN = 24
```

But that's perfectly acceptable as a file handle to Perl. There are four things that Perl accepts as file handles:

- A reference to an IO object.

  ```
  >perl -e"my $fh = *STDOUT{IO}; CORE::say($fh 'foo');"
  foo
  ```
- A glob that contains a reference to an IO object.

  ```
  >perl -e"my $fh = *STDOUT; CORE::say($fh 'foo');"
  foo
  ```
- A reference to a glob that contains a reference to an IO object.

  ```
  >perl -e"my $fh = \*STDOUT; CORE::say($fh 'foo');"
  foo
  ```
- A "symbolic reference" to a glob that contains a reference to an IO object.

  ```
  >perl -e"my $fh = 'STDOUT'; CORE::say($fh 'foo');"
  foo
  ```

  This type doesn't work under strict refs, though.

  ```
  >perl -Mstrict -e"my $fh = 'STDOUT'; CORE::say($fh 'foo');"
  Can't use string ("STDOUT") as a symbol ref while "strict refs" in use at -e line 1.
  ```

> *What do I have to do to always get a usable file handle from select's return value?*

As demonstrated above, it already returns a perfectly usable file handle. If `XMLout` doesn't support it, then it's a bug in `XMLout`. You could work around it as follows:

```
my $fh = select();
if (!ref($fh) && ref(\$fh) ne 'GLOB') {
   no strict qw( refs );
   $fh = \*$fh;
}
```

This can also be used to make the handle usable in a strict environment

---

As bad as XML::Simple is at reading XML, it's a million times worse at generating it. See [Why is XML::Simple Discouraged?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33267765/why-is-xmlsimple-discouraged).

Consider [XML::LibXML](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?XML::LibXML) or [XML::Twig](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?XML::Twig) if you're modifying XML.

Consider [XML::Writer](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?XML::Writer) if you're generating XML.

Comment: Your code did the trick! The magic seems to be not using strict. My original code also works, when I comment out `use strict;`. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

The point of [select](http://p3rl.org/select) is you don't need to specify the handle at all, since it's the default one.

```
sub test {
    print "@_\n";
}
```

That's also the reason why `select` isn't recommended: it introduces global state which is hard to track and debug.

Comment: Using this file handle with print is just my test case, whether `$fh` really can be used as a file handle.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you shouldn't use XML::Simple , because it will need lots of work to make sure that your output will generate consistent XML. At least make sure you're using the appropriate `ForceArray` parameters.

Instead of doing filehandle shenanigans, why don't you use the simpler

```
print XMLout($data, %options);
```

... instead of trying to pass a default filehandle around?

Comment: Using XML::Simple was not my choice. It is used in old code I need to maintain. The reason, why I want to use the OutputFile option is, that I do not want to store the XML output in a variable, when it can be directly written to the file handle, where it needs to go.