# Perl XML::Easy: read SVG path data

Tags: xml, perl, svg

I am working on a thing which will need to get at the path data of individual paths in an `SVG` file, so that I can generate similar paths.

After looking in horror at the plethora of c/c++ libraries for handling SVG files, I decided to use perl (since it is more suited to the job of sorting through sausages of SVG path data) with an XML parser. For some reason I chose `XML::Easy` (I had a good reason. That was yesterday and I can't remember what it was. Probably the fact that it's supposed to be `Easy`) as the parser.

However, I have not found any tutorials or documentation other than perldoc and metacpan.

I have managed to read my file into an `XML::Easy::Element` reference using `xml10_read_document`, but I have no idea how to get at the actual path data.

How do I get the path sausage from the `XML::Easy::Element` reference?

Edit: the sausage I am referring to is the d attribute in the path. EG: from

```
<svg>
[...]
<g id=something>
<path d="M350.41,62.567v0.135l1.118,0.04v-0.135L350.41,62.567z
    M351.898,60.655c-0.242,0-0.433,0.059-0.572,0.175c-0.089,0.104-0.179,0.207-0.269,0.311l-0.014-0.445l-0.875-0.013v0.31
        l0.458,0.067l-0.041,1.421l0.498,0.006l0.014-0.754c0.197-0.449,0.438-0.673,0.72-0.673c0.193,0,0.29,0.11,0.29,0.329
        c0,0.108-0.025,0.223-0.074,0.344l0.316,0.081c0.085-0.148,0.128-0.312,0.128-0.491c0-0.185-0.047-0.34-0.142-0.465
        C352.228,60.723,352.082,60.655,351.898,60.655z
      M350.572,62.816l-0.027,0.922l0.525-0.08l0.006-0.835L350.572,62.816z"/>
</g>
[...]
</svg>
```

I would like to extract

```perl
"M350.41,62.567v0.135l1.118,0.04v-0.135L350.41,62.567z
 M351.898,60.655c-0.242,0-0.433,0.059-0.572,0.175c-0.089,0.104-0.179,0.207-0.269,0.311l-0.014-0.445l-0.875-0.013v0.31
 l0.458,0.067l-0.041,1.421l0.498,0.006l0.014-0.754c0.197-0.449,0.438-0.673,0.72-0.673c0.193,0,0.29,0.11,0.29,0.329      c0,0.108-0.025,0.223-0.074,0.344l0.316,0.081c0.085-0.148,0.128-0.312,0.128-0.491c0-0.185-0.047-0.34-0.142-0.465
        C352.228,60.723,352.082,60.655,351.898,60.655z
      M350.572,62.816l-0.027,0.922l0.525-0.08l0.006-0.835L350.572,62.816z"
```

Comment: Sausages? I'm German and I appreciate sausages, especially _mit Senf_, but I have no idea what you are talking about. ;)

Comment: Can you add a short SVG example file to show which bits you are actually trying to access? See [mcve].

Comment: Hmmmm, sausages!! Please provide a [mcve], thank you.

Comment: @simbabque added an example file

Comment: If you want those paths and nothing else, you don't even need to use an XML parser. This is a case were I think a simple regex is fine.

Comment: @simbabque Might do that, but then I would have missed a learning opportunity. This is the first time I have ever used an XML parser, and I don't want to give up just because the documentation is complicated.

Comment: Even though a regex would probably be able to do this reasonably, you would still have to deal with things like XML decoding, and it wouldn't extend well to more complicated requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After diving into XML::Easy's docs for a bit, I think this would work:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Easy::Text 'xml10_read_document';
use XML::Easy::NodeBasics qw(xml_e_content_twine xml_e_type_name xml_e_attribute);
use List::Util 'first';

my $svg = <<'SVG';
<svg>
[...]
<g id="something">
<path d="M350.41,62.567v0.135l1.118,0.04v-0.135L350.41,62.567z
    M351.898,60.655c-0.242,0-0.433,0.059-0.572,0.175c-0.089,0.104-0.179,0.207-0.269,0.311l-0.014-0.445l-0.875-0.013v0.31
        l0.458,0.067l-0.041,1.421l0.498,0.006l0.014-0.754c0.197-0.449,0.438-0.673,0.72-0.673c0.193,0,0.29,0.11,0.29,0.329
        c0,0.108-0.025,0.223-0.074,0.344l0.316,0.081c0.085-0.148,0.128-0.312,0.128-0.491c0-0.185-0.047-0.34-0.142-0.465
        C352.228,60.723,352.082,60.655,351.898,60.655z
      M350.572,62.816l-0.027,0.922l0.525-0.08l0.006-0.835L350.572,62.816z"/>
</g>
[...]
</svg>
SVG

my $root = xml10_read_document($svg);
my $contents = xml_e_content_twine($root);
my $g = first { ref $_ and xml_e_type_name($_) eq 'g' and xml_e_attribute($_, 'id') eq 'something' } @$contents;
my $g_contents = xml_e_content_twine($g);
my $path = first { ref $_ and xml_e_type_name($_) eq 'path' } @$g_contents;
my $sausage = xml_e_attribute($path, 'd');
```

Hardly seems "easy" to me. I'd recommend any of the XPath or CSS equipped parsers instead.

Answer (score 3):

Here is how I'd do it with [Mojo::DOM](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::DOM):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Mojo::DOM;

my $svg = <<'SVG';
<svg>
[...]
<g id="something">
<path d="M350.41,62.567v0.135l1.118,0.04v-0.135L350.41,62.567z
    M351.898,60.655c-0.242,0-0.433,0.059-0.572,0.175c-0.089,0.104-0.179,0.207-0.269,0.311l-0.014-0.445l-0.875-0.013v0.31
        l0.458,0.067l-0.041,1.421l0.498,0.006l0.014-0.754c0.197-0.449,0.438-0.673,0.72-0.673c0.193,0,0.29,0.11,0.29,0.329
        c0,0.108-0.025,0.223-0.074,0.344l0.316,0.081c0.085-0.148,0.128-0.312,0.128-0.491c0-0.185-0.047-0.34-0.142-0.465
        C352.228,60.723,352.082,60.655,351.898,60.655z
      M350.572,62.816l-0.027,0.922l0.525-0.08l0.006-0.835L350.572,62.816z"/>
</g>
[...]
</svg>
SVG

my $dom = Mojo::DOM->new->xml(1)->parse($svg);
my $sausage = $dom->at('path')->{d};
```

Or if you want to get it from a specific `<g>` tag instead of the first one:

```
my $sausage = $dom->at('g#something path')->{d};
```

Comment: One of the reasons I chose XML::Easy is that it is in apt. I can't find Mojo::DOM in apt, so even though it looks easier, I'll accept the other answer.

Comment: @MarkGardner It would be part of the Mojolicious distribution.

Comment: @MarkGardner Another common option that would be nearly as simple would be [XML::LibXML](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::LibXML). I'm not quite as familiar with XPath to show an example.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't remember the reason you choose to use `XML::Easy`, consider using [XML::Simple](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Simple) instead :-) :

```
use XML::Simple qw( XMLin ) ;

my $svg = q{
    <svg width="190" height="160" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <path d="M10 10 C 20 20, 40 20, 50 10" stroke="black" fill="transparent"/>
      <path d="M70 10 C 70 20, 120 20, 120 10" stroke="black" fill="transparent"/>
      <path d="M70 10 C 70 20, 120 20, 120 10" stroke="black" fill="transparent"/>
    </svg>
};

my $decoded = XMLin( $svg, ForceArray => 1 ) ;

foreach my $path ( @{ $decoded->{ path } } ){
    my $data = $path->{d} ;
    my $stroke = $path->{stroke} ;
    my $fill = $path->{ fill } ;
    ...
}
```

Where `$decoded->{ path }` is:

```
 [
     {
         d      => "M10 10 C 20 20, 40 20, 50 10",
         fill   => "transparent",
         stroke => "black"
     },
     {
         d      => "M70 10 C 70 20, 120 20, 120 10",
         fill   => "transparent",
         stroke => "black"
     },
     {
         d      => "M70 10 C 70 20, 120 20, 120 10",
         fill   => "transparent",
         stroke => "black"
     }
 ]
```

**BEWARE** : As pointed by Grinnz, don't use `XML::Simple` for anything else more complex than a trivial SVG.

Comment: Please don't suggest XML::Simple for any reason. See [the answers here for why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33267765/why-is-xmlsimple-discouraged).

Comment: @Grinnz really? For a simple SVG? No one reason in the posted link meets this very trivial case. No one.

Comment: Yes, because every other option (aside from XML::Easy, apparently) is simpler and won't break when trying to do something more complex.

Comment: You're right as always, off course.. but just for doing easy philosophy: Isn't like saying to use the chainsaw to cut the bread, because one day it could happen to have to cut something harder? :-)

Comment: In my opinion XML::Simple is the chainsaw, but it's the one without a handle. ;)

Comment: But what if I have multiple paths?