# perl mismatched tag, problem = XML::Simple module?

Tags: perl, raspberry-pi, cpanel, raspberry-pi3, cpanel-xmlapi

when i try to run this script to send my ip to cpanel...

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# dns_update_script.pl
#
# Version 1.0 - 16.01.2012
#
# PERL script to dynamically update the IP of a host via the cPanel-API. This
# script was written to work with the Finnish hoster Neobitti but it might work
# with other hosters which use cPanel too.
#
# Copyright (C) 2012 Stefan Gofferje - http://stefan.gofferje.net/
#
# This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
# modify it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as
# published by the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the
# License, or (at your option) any later version.
#
# This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful, but
# WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
# MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the GNU
# General Public License for more details.
#
# You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
# along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software
# Foundation, Inc., 51 Franklin Street, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA  02110-1301, USA.
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
use strict;
use LWP::UserAgent;
use MIME::Base64;
use XML::Simple;
use Data::Dumper;
# --- Command line parameters ------------------------------------------------
my $param_domain=$ARGV[0];
my $param_host=$ARGV[1];
my $param_ip=$ARGV[2];
# --- cPanel information -----------------------------------------------------
# Storing passwords in clear text is ugly!
my $cpanel_domain = "yourdomain.com";
my $user = "yourcpaneluser";
my $pass = "yourcpanelpassword";
my $auth = "Basic " . MIME::Base64::encode( $user . ":" . $pass );
# --- Deactivate SSL certificate validation ----------------------------------
# This is ugly but neccessary because Neobitti uses self-signed SSL
# certificates which will fail validation
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new(ssl_opts => { verify_hostname => 0 });
# --- Find out the linenumber for the A-record we want to change -------------
sub getlinenumber_a {
  my $domain=$_[0];
  my $hostname=$_[1].".";
  my $xml = new XML::Simple;
  my $request = HTTP::Request->new( GET => "https://$cpanel_domain:2083/xml-api/cpanel?cpanel_xmlapi_module=ZoneEdit&cpanel_xmlapi_func=fetchzon
e&domain=$domain" );
  $request->header( Authorization => $auth );
  my $response = $ua->request($request);
  my $zone = $xml->XMLin($response->content);
  my $linenumber="";
  if ($zone->{'data'}->{'status'} eq "1") {
    my $count = @{$zone->{'data'}->{'record'}};
    my $oldip="";
    for (my $item=0;$item<=$count;$item++) {
        my $name=$zone->{'data'}->{'record'}[$item]->{'name'};
        my $type=$zone->{'data'}->{'record'}[$item]->{'type'};
        if ( ($name eq $hostname) && ($type eq "A") ) {
          $linenumber=$zone->{'data'}->{'record'}[$item]->{'Line'};
          $oldip=$zone->{'data'}->{'record'}[$item]->{'record'};
          print "Found $hostname in line $linenumber with IP $oldip.\n"; # DEBUG
        }
    }
  } else {
    $linenumber="0";
    print $zone->{'event'}->{'data'}->{'statusmsg;'}
  }
  return($linenumber);
}
# --- Change the IP address record for a certain linenumber ------------------
sub setip {
  my $domain=$_[0];
  my $linenumber=$_[1];
  my $newip=$_[2];
  my $result="";
  my $xml = new XML::Simple;
  my $request = HTTP::Request->new( GET => "https://$cpanel_domain:2083/xml-api/cpanel?cpanel_xmlapi_module=ZoneEdit&cpanel_xmlapi_func=edit_zone_record&domain=$domain&line=$linenumber&address=$newip" );
  $request->header( Authorization => $auth );
  my $response = $ua->request($request);

  my $reply = $xml->XMLin($response->content);
  if ($reply->{'data'}->{'status'} eq "1") {
    $result="1";
  } else {
    $result=$reply->{'data'}->{'statusmsg'};
  }
  return($result);
}
# --- Main procedure ---------------------------------------------------------
print "Trying to find the linenumber for $param_host in $param_domain...\n";
my $line=getlinenumber_a($param_domain,$param_host);
if ( ($line ne "0") && ($line ne "") ) {
  print "Trying to update IP...\n";
  my $result=setip ($param_domain,$line,$param_ip);
  if ($result eq "1") {
    print "Update successful!\n";
  } else {
    print "$result\n";
  }
} else {
  print "Error - check domain and hostname!\n";
}
```

---

... I get this error:

```
mismatched tag at line 37, column 2, byte 4634 at /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/perl5/5.28/XML/Parser.pm line 187.
XML::Simple called at dns_update_script.pl line 55.
```

---

in the cPanel information section I have filled in my cpanel username, password and domain in my file (not this one). I have filled this in in open text like a noob and ignored this thing:

```
  my $auth = "Basic " . MIME::Base64::encode( $user . ":" . $pass );
```

but i dont think this is the problem.

I think the problem is in the XML::Simple module because the script stops when that module is called it seems like to me but idk. pls help.

Comment: The [documentation for XML::Simple](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Simple) even says to not use it in favor of the many better alternatives...  but without seeing an example of the xml you're feeding it, can't really blame it yet... Maybe the xml is malformed like the error suggests?

Comment: $result = $expat->parse($arg);             <---- the error happens on this line. line 187.

Comment: You need to include an example of the xml data you're trying to parse in your question.

Comment: That script also doesn't appear to do any error checking that the http request succeeded before trying to use its results, which is also something worth investigating. (I don't know if it's a copy & paste error or what, but there's a newline in one of the URL strings that shouldn't be there)

Comment: `encode( $user . ":" . $pass )` should be `encode( $user . ":" . $pass, "" )`, but that's not likely to be the issue in question.

Answer (score 4):

You are getting that error because the string you pass to `XMLin` isn't valid XML. You will need to fix the input to be valid XML.

While [I strongly recommend against using XML::Simple](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33267765/589924), it's not because of problems parsing XML. The underlying parser used in this situation (`expat` via XML::Parser) isn't known for wrongly claiming valid XML is invalid.

Your program should be checking if the request is successful (`$response->is_success`). I suspect you are getting some kind of error (e.g. 403 Forbidden). `$response->status_line` is useful to add to your error message.

(If the request is successful, perhaps you should print out `$response->as_string` to examine the response to get a better idea of what is happening.)

Answer (score 0):

I just used this shell script instead and hooked it up to my crontab and now it runs the script every hour and it works fine.

https://github.com/CpanelInc/cpanel-dynamicdns-tools

for my raspberry pi web server