# How to return XML with Dancer2::Plugin::REST?

Tags: xml, perl

I'm successfully using Dancer2::Plugin::REST to return JSON from my web server when users access mydomain.com/api/1.json .While retaining this feature, how can I use Dancer2::Plugin2::REST to return XML when users access mydomain.com/api/1.xml ?

My config.yml contains this section:

```
serializers:
  json: JSON
  yml:  YAML
  yaml: YAML
  dump: Dumper
  xml:  XML
```

My lib/MyApp/API.pm looks like this:

```
package MyApp::API;

use Dancer2;

use Dancer2::Plugin::REST;
prepare_serializer_for_format;

get '/1.:format' => sub {
    return { 'temperature' => '10', 'date' => '2019-09-01' };
};

true;
```

As expected I get the correct JSON snippet when running:

```
curl -H 'Accept-Type: text/json' https://<mydomain>/api/1.json
```

But when I run:

```
curl -H 'Accept-Type: text/xml' https://<mydomain>/api/1.xml
```

or

```
curl -H 'Accept-Type: application/xml' https://<mydomain>/api/1.xml
```

or

```
curl https://<mydomain>/api/1.xml
```

I get a server error in response:

```
Internal Server Error

Reference {"exception" => "Reference {\"date\" => \"2019-09-01\",\"tem...} did not pass type constraint "Str" (in $self->{"content"}) at /usr/local/share/perl/5.26.1/Dancer2/Core/Response.pm line 122
    "Str" is a subtype of "Value"
    Reference {"exception" => "Reference {\"date\" => \"2019-09-01\",\"tem...} did not pass type constraint "Value" (in $self->{"content"})
    "Value" is defined as: (defined($_) and not ref($_))
```

I expected to get a XML response, not a server error. What am I missing?

Comment: Try `application/xml`

Comment: Thanks ikegami, but unfortunately curl -H 'Accept-Type: application/xml' https://<mydomain>/api/1.xml changes nothing, the exact same server error is returned.

Comment: I've now updated my question to reflect this.

Comment: By the way, do you realize that this will use XML::Simple, [a module you should avoid](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33267765/589924) because it's insanely hard to use the data structures or XML is returns?

Comment: I've been looking into this for a while, and I've come to the conclusion that the list of extensions is hardcoded to `yaml`, `yml`, `json`, `dump`.

Comment: @ikegami: Thanks for looking into this. I guess XML is less popular than it used to be. I'll have to generate my XML responses in some other way.