# perl XML::LibXML get direct child text node content

Tags: perl, xml-libxml

Like in this snippet:

```
<p>content 1 of p <span>content of span</span> content 2 of p </p>
```

I would like to only obtain the following:
`content 1 of p` and `content 2 of p`, not `content of span`.

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Don't listen to @Nilesh Jain; XML::Simple's own documentation warns you against using it for the reason outlined in [Why is XML::Simple "discouraged"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33267765/589924). In short, it's an extremely hard to use module. What simply requires `$node->findnodes('text()')` with XML::LibXML would be extremely convoluted and error-prone with XML::Simple.

Comment: Don't use `XML::Simple`. It had had its place many years ago but its use has been discouraged by its own author, in its own documentation, for many years now.  (Go and actually read the _first_ paragraph on the link that @NileshJain  supplied.)  Its own author wrote a tutorial on another module (`XML::LibXML`, and it's a good tutorial). Use either `XML::LibXML` or `XML::Twig`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using an XPath:

```
for my $text_node ($node->findnodes('text()')) {
   say $text_node;
}
```

Without using an XPath:

```
for my $child_node ($node->childNodes()) {
   next if $child_node->nodeType != XML_TEXT_NODE;

   say $child_node;
}
```

Both output the following:

```
content 1 of p
 content 2 of p
```

The rest of the program:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw( say );

use XML::LibXML qw( XML_TEXT_NODE );

my $xml = '<p>content 1 of p <span>content of span</span> content 2 of p </p>';

my $doc = XML::LibXML->new->parse_string($xml);
my $node = $doc->documentElement();
```

Comment: Thanks @ikegami This helps a lot. The XPath approach is neat.

Comment: You can, of course, embed it part of a larger XPath (e.g. `$doc->findnodes('/p/text()')`)