# Perl XML to Hash drop last xml node and force an array

Tags: arrays, xml, perl, hash

I have an XML that I need to convert to a hash in a specific format that requires some nodes to be in an array. I've tried XML::Simple but can't get rid of one xml node level.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Data::Dumper::Simple;
use XML::Simple;

use warnings;
use strict;

my $xml = <<'XML';
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<release id="9999" status="Accepted">
  <images>
    <image height="511" type="primary" uri="" uri150="" width="600"/>
    <image height="519" type="secondary" uri="" uri150="" width="600"/>
    <image height="521" type="secondary" uri="" uri150="" width="600"/>
    <image height="217" type="secondary" uri="" uri150="" width="500"/>
    <image height="597" type="secondary" uri="" uri150="" width="600"/>
    <image height="89" type="secondary" uri="" uri150="" width="600"/>
  </images>
  <artists>
    <artist>
      <id>45</id>
      <name>Aphex Twin</name>
      <anv/>
      <join/>
      <role/>
      <tracks/>
    </artist>
  </artists>
</release>
XML

my $xml_hash = XMLin($xml, ForceArray => qr{image}x );
print Dumper $xml_hash;
```

Desired output

```
       'images' => [
                     {
                       'type' => 'primary',
                       'width' => 600,
                       'resource_url' => '',
                       'uri150' => '',
                       'height' => 511,
                       'uri' => ''
                     },
                     {
                       'width' => 600,
                       'type' => 'secondary',
                       'resource_url' => '',
                       'uri150' => '',
                       'uri' => '',
                       'height' => 519
                     }, etc...
```

What I'm getting with my sample code is

```
$xml_hash = {
              'images' => [
                            {
                              'image' => [
                                           {
                                             'uri150' => '',
                                             'type' => 'primary',
                                             'uri' => '',
                                             'height' => '511',
                                             'width' => '600'
                                           },
                                           {
                                             'type' => 'secondary',
                                             'uri150' => '',
                                             'uri' => '',
                                             'height' => '519',
                                             'width' => '600'
                                           },
                                           {
                                             'uri' => '',
                                             'height' => '521',
                                             'width' => '600',
                                             'type' => 'secondary',
                                             'uri150' => ''
                                           },
                              etc...
```

How do I get rid of

> 'image' => [

and have

> 'images' => [

contain all the hashes ?

Thanks; George

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33267765/why-is-xmlsimple-discouraged

Answer (score 2):

Any attempt to represent a whole XML document as a Perl data structure will be fraught with edge cases and inconvenient designs by the nature of the two formats. There are many options to parse and traverse XML in a way suited to the format, like [XML::LibXML](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::LibXML) and [XML::Twig](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Twig). Here is how I would approach this with [Mojo::DOM](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::DOM) (which uses CSS selectors for traversal):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Mojo::DOM;
use Mojo::Util 'dumper';

my $xml = <<'XML';
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<release id="9999" status="Accepted">
  <images>
    <image height="511" type="primary" uri="" uri150="" width="600"/>
    <image height="519" type="secondary" uri="" uri150="" width="600"/>
    <image height="521" type="secondary" uri="" uri150="" width="600"/>
    <image height="217" type="secondary" uri="" uri150="" width="500"/>
    <image height="597" type="secondary" uri="" uri150="" width="600"/>
    <image height="89" type="secondary" uri="" uri150="" width="600"/>
  </images>
  <artists>
    <artist>
      <id>45</id>
      <name>Aphex Twin</name>
      <anv/>
      <join/>
      <role/>
      <tracks/>
    </artist>
  </artists>
</release>
XML

my $dom = Mojo::DOM->new->xml(1)->parse($xml);
my @images = $dom->find('release#9999 > images > image')->map('attr')->each;
print dumper \@images;
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    "height" => 511,
    "type" => "primary",
    "uri" => "",
    "uri150" => "",
    "width" => 600
  },
  {
    "height" => 519,
    "type" => "secondary",
    "uri" => "",
    "uri150" => "",
    "width" => 600
  },
  {
    "height" => 521,
    "type" => "secondary",
    "uri" => "",
    "uri150" => "",
    "width" => 600
  },
  {
    "height" => 217,
    "type" => "secondary",
    "uri" => "",
    "uri150" => "",
    "width" => 500
  },
  {
    "height" => 597,
    "type" => "secondary",
    "uri" => "",
    "uri150" => "",
    "width" => 600
  },
  {
    "height" => 89,
    "type" => "secondary",
    "uri" => "",
    "uri150" => "",
    "width" => 600
  }
]
```

Comment: I hoped for magic bullet, but I get your point, what I posted is just a sample of xml, there are many cases where I would need to use Mojo to extract what I need into specific hash format, I already have bunch of code that expect the hash as from web service. Trying to work with xml data dump instead of web service. Thanks !

Comment: @George It will take work to adapt various XML into the structures you need, but in the end it will be more consistent, flexible and maintainable.

Comment: hum, If a prefix is used for an attribute, this creates a hash element that uses the prefix, even though the prefix is meaningless outside of the document.

Answer (score 2):

[XML::Simple](http://p3rl.org/XML::Simple) discourages its own use.

Here's how you can get the array of hashes using [XML::LibXML](http://p3rl.org/XML::LibXML):

```
use XML::LibXML;

my $dom = XML::LibXML->load_xml(string => $xml);

my @images = map +{
    map { $_->name => $_->value } $_->findnodes('@*')
}, $dom->findnodes('/release/images/image');
```

Comment: This ignores the namespace of the attribute, so it could cause conflicts.  Would be better to ignore attributes in the non-null namespace so that extensions --the "X" in "XML"-- don't cause problems. But it's not likely to matter.

Comment: @ikegami: Yes, and if the XML declares a namespace for the root node, the resulting array will be empty.

Comment: As it should. That's the point I was making. You treat nodes `{}release` and nodes `{http://foo}release` as different elements (which is good), but you treat attributes `{}height` and `{http://foo}height` as the same, picking one at random as the height (which is bad, but unlikely to happen).