# how to add/delete to xml file without replacing original value?

Tags: xml, perl

I would like to do add/delete function based on the user's input file.

i have two files. one is user's input file and another one is original xml file.
First is checking whether user's request ID is exist in original config or not . if it is exist it will perform delete function , if no ID is exit in original config file, it will perform add function.based on the user's input file request.I start learning perl script.kindly help to suggest how to do add/delete function to the original config file . thanks alot :)

below is my user's input file

```
add:L83A:55FIP:11:18: #addfunction:DesignID:ProcessID:registerIDs
del:L83A:FRP:149:155:194: #deletefunction:DesignID:ProcessID:registerIDs
```

here is my original config xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>

<Sigma>
<Run>
<DESIGN_ID>L83A</DESIGN_ID>
<PROCESS_ID>55FIP</PROCESS_ID>
<RegisterList>
<Register>70</Register>
<Register>155</Register>
</RegisterList>
</Run>
<Run>
<DESIGN_ID>L83A</DESIGN_ID>
<PROCESS_ID>FRP</PROCESS_ID>
<RegisterList>
<Register>141</Register>
<Register>149</Register>
<Register>151</Register>
<Register>152</Register>
<Register>155</Register>
<Register>194</Register>
</RegisterList>
</Run>
</Sigma>
```

so the result should comeout by writing xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>

<Sigma>
<Run>
<DESIGN_ID>L83A</DESIGN_ID>
<PROCESS_ID>55FIP</PROCESS_ID>
<RegisterList>
<Register>70</Register>
<Register>155</Register>
<Register>11</Register>
<Register>18</Register>
</RegisterList>
</Run>
<Run>
<DESIGN_ID>L83A</DESIGN_ID>
<PROCESS_ID>FRP</PROCESS_ID>
<RegisterList>
<Register>141</Register>
<Register>151</Register>
<Register>152</Register>
</RegisterList>
</Run>
</Sigma>
```

but my code only replace for 11 and 18 instead of adding . and also cannot perform delete function :(

here is my code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Simple;
use Data::Dumper;
use feature 'say';
my $filename = 'new.txt';
my $data;
my $run;
open(FILE, '<', $filename) or die $!;
foreach $run(@{XMLin('sigma_loader.xml')->{Run}})  # see how it looks
{
  $data->{$run->{DESIGN_ID}}->{$run->{PROCESS_ID}} =
  {map { $_ => 1 } @{$run->{RegisterList}->{Register}}};
}
while (<FILE>)
{   my $line = $_;
   chomp $line ;
my ($action,$design_id, $process_id, @register_ids) = split /:/, $line; #split the line with add:design_ID:process_ID:register_ID

if(exists $data->{$design_id})
{
 if (exists $data->{$design_id}->{$process_id})
  {
   my $register_id;
foreach $register_id (@register_ids) {
   if (exists $data->{$design_id}->{$process_id}->{$register_id}) {
    say " $design_id: $register_id - existing register ID";
   }
  else {
   say "  $design_id : $register_id - no existing register ID";
   }
   if($action eq 'add')
   {
    $data->{$design_id}->{$process_id}= {$register_id , '1'};
     print Dumper($data);

   }
   if($action eq 'del')
   {
    my $xml = XMLin('sigma_loader.xml', ForceArray => 1, KeepRoot => 1);
    delete $xml->{DESIGN_ID}[0]{PROCESS_ID}[0]{RegisterList}[0]{Register}{$register_id};
    print XMLout($xml, KeepRoot => 1)
  }
  }
}
 else{
   say "$design_id: doesn't have $process_id";
  }
  }
 else
{
   say "$design_id does't exist in data";
}
}
```

Comment: For starters, read [Why is XML::Simple Discouraged?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33267765/589924)

Answer (score 1):

*Don't* use `XML::Simple`, use a proper XML module like [`XML::LibXML`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::LibXML). This produces your expected output (with likely-insignificant whitespace differences):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use XML::LibXML;

my $xmlfile = 'sigma_loader.xml';
my $commandfile = 'commands.txt';
my $DEBUG = 1;

my $doc = XML::LibXML->load_xml(location => $xmlfile);

open my $fh, '<', $commandfile or die "$commandfile: $!";
while ( my $line = <$fh> ) {
    chomp($line);
    my ($action,$design_id,$proc_id,@register_ids) = split /:/, $line;
    my @runs = $doc->findnodes("/Sigma/Run[DESIGN_ID='$design_id'"
        ." and PROCESS_ID='$proc_id']");
    print STDERR "Found ".@runs." Run nodes matching DESIGN_ID="
        ."$design_id PROCESS_ID=$proc_id\n" if $DEBUG;
    for my $run (@runs) {
        my ($reglist) = $run->findnodes('./RegisterList')
            or die "Failed to find RegisterList";
        my @regs = $reglist->findnodes('./Register['
            .join(' or ', map {"text()='$_'"} @register_ids).']');
        print STDERR "Found ".@regs." Register nodes for IDs "
            .join(',',@register_ids)."\n" if $DEBUG;
        if ($action eq 'add') {
            my %regs = map { $_->textContent => $_ } @regs;
            for my $regid (@register_ids) {
                next if exists $regs{$regid};
                my $reg = $doc->createElement('Register');
                $reg->appendText($regid);
                $reglist->appendChild($reg);
                print STDERR "Added Register $regid\n" if $DEBUG;
            }
        }
        elsif ($action eq 'del') {
            for my $reg (@regs) {
                print STDERR "Removing Register "
                    .$reg->textContent."\n" if $DEBUG;
                $reglist->removeChild($reg);
            }
        }
        else { die "Unknown action '$action'" }
    }
}

print $doc->toString(1);
```

Note this makes a few assumptions, like not validating your commands file, assuming that values like `$design_id` and `$proc_id` won't break the XPath quoting, assuming there's only one `RegisterList` per `Run`, or assuming that within each `RegisterList`, the `Register`s are unique. You may have to adjust some of this depending on the specifications of your input files.

Comment: when i run the code , i get the error Can't locate XML\LibXML.pm in @INC. i tried to install cpan XML::LibLXML in command pmt.but getting time out error. is there anyway to install LibXML ? :(

Comment: Timeout sounds like a network issue. What OS are you on? Depending on that, you may be able to install the module using the system's package manager, for example on Debian/Ubuntu, `sudo apt-get install libxml-libxml-perl`. If you're installing the module from source, like via `cpan` or `cpanm`, you'll need the `libxml2` development package installed (on Debian/Ubuntu, `sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev`).

Comment: i am using microsoft windows version 1809 (OS build 17763.1158)

Comment: @PannPhyuPhway [Strawberry Perl](http://strawberryperl.com/) comes with that module preinstalled, and for ActivePerl you should be able to install [XML-LibXML](https://code.activestate.com/ppm/XML-LibXML/) with `ppm`.

Comment: seems like  my network doesn't have permission for installing such XML:LibXML. :( is there any other way for adding/deleting by using XML::Simple ?