# Getting extra variable in XML to JSON conversion using perl

Tags: perl

**My Program is giving extra variable $t in output. Can anyone help me on this?**

```
use XML::XML2JSON;
```

## xml content

```
my $XML = '<file><sno>1</sno><process>VALID</process><validation_type>C</validation_type><file_type>HTML</file_type><line>2</line><column>78</column><status>0</status><type>Warning</type><code>001</code><rule>aligning content.</rule><desc>Check that non-breaking space.</desc></file>';
  


my $XML2JSON = XML::XML2JSON->new();
my $JSON = $XML2JSON->convert($XML);
print $JSON;
```

Output - Extra variable is coming $t

```
{
    "@encoding": "UTF-8",
    "@version": "1.0",
    "file": {
        "status": {
            "$t": "0"
        },
        "rule": {
            "$t": "aligning content."
        },
        "validation_type": {
            "$t": "C"
        },
        "process": {
            "$t": "VALID"
        },
        "sno": {
            "$t": "1"
        },
        "file_type": {
            "$t": "HTML"
        },
        "desc": {
            "$t": "Check that non-breaking space."
        },
        "type": {
            "$t": "Warning"
        },
        "code": {
            "$t": "001"
        },
        "line": {
            "$t": "2"
        },
        "column": {
            "$t": "78"
        }
    }
}
```

**Expected output is:**

```
{
   "sno": "1",
   "process": "VALID",
   "validation_type": "C",
   "file_type": "HTML",
   "line": "2",
   "column": "78",
   "status": "0",
   "type": "Warning",
   "code": "001",
   "rule": "aligning content.",
   "desc": "Check that non-breaking space."
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$t` is `content key` as mentioned in the [XML::XML2JSON](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::XML2JSON#content_key) documentation.

---

If your intention is to convert from `XML` to `JSON`, I would recommend to use `XML::Simple` and later you can encode using `JSON.pm`.

Code below:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use JSON;
use XML::Simple;

#Create an object
my $xmlSimple = new XML::Simple;

my $XML = '<file><sno>1</sno><process>VALID</process><validation_type>C</validation_type><file_type>HTML</file_type><line>2</line><column>78</column><status>0</status><type>Warning</type><code>001</code><rule>aligning content.</rule><desc>Check that non-breaking space.</desc></file>';

#either we can pass a variable or a xml file which contains xml data
my $dataXML = $xmlSimple->XMLin($XML); 

my $jsonString = encode_json($dataXML);

print $jsonString;
```

**Output:**

```
{
    "process":"VALID",
    "line":"2",
    "column":"78",
    "type":"Warning",
    "file_type":"HTML",
    "sno":"1",
    "status":"0",
    "rule":"aligning content.",
    "code":"001",
    "desc":"Check that non-breaking space.",
    "validation_type":"C"
}
```

Comment: I wouldnt use XML::Simple, as even the author disourages its use. [Why is XML::Simple Discouraged?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33267765/why-is-xmlsimple-discouraged)

Comment: @GeorgMavridis okay. As I have already done these kind of assignment using `XML::Simple`, just provided the solution. If its not suitable then questioner can go for `XML::LibXML`.

Comment: Don't use XML::Simple.