# How to convert XML attributes to elements in Perl?

Tags: json, xml, perl

My monitoring application reads only if the XML is presented as elements.
But my source application is only providing JSON outputs. I tried to convert the JSON output to XML using the following perl code:

```
# Capture the API output
if ($ApiResponse->is_error())
{
    my $errorMsg = $ApiResponse->status_line();
    print "error : $errorMsg\n Sending Connectivity Error\n";
}
elsif ($ApiResponse->is_success()) 
{       
    my $JSONOutput = JSON->new->utf8->convert_blessed(1)->decode($ApiResponse->content()); 
    my $XMLOutput = XMLout($JSONOutput);
}
```

My output XML looks like

```
<opt>
  <rowset affectedRows="444" dbname="custom" osname="SOMNI" tblname="tsiobm">
    <rows FirstOccurrence="1594021452" Node="host" RowSerial="250" Serial="98567869" Severity="5" Summary="SDV134E TWS JOB=A76DT803 JOB04878 WS=PROD APPL=A76DT80S ERROR=JCL  ID=DT803" Status="20" Prob_nr="SDV134E" />
    <rows FirstOccurrence="1594130034" Node="router-ess-vpn.elber.west" RowSerial="329" Serial="98639905" Severity="5" Summary="Tunnel2 Default Interface Ping/Default Interface Ping fail for 10.23.9.5: ICMP timeout" Status="20" Prob_nr="SDV_IDWN" />
    <rows FirstOccurrence="1594126166" Node="host" RowSerial="327" Serial="98637375" Severity="5" Summary="+SDV131E U00PR T09R905V 03:05:07 ACICSN1 RACINITI T09R9 STCOPC" Status="20" Prob_nr="SDV131E" />
    <rows FirstOccurrence="1594012257" Node="upjbxs1_adapter_9128" RowSerial="233" Serial="98561743" Severity="5" Summary="HTTP::Globo::Webserver: CRITICAL; Details: Fehler aufgetreten! - 3/3 " Status="20" Prob_nr="GSA_HTTP_Status" />
  </rowset>
</opt>
```

How can I get the output in elements and not attributes. Its necessary for the monitoring to work?

Comment: What do you want the XML to look like?

Comment: And what XML module are you using? Where's `XMLout` coming from? Needs a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you, I realized how complicated XML::Simple is, will not use it hence forth.
But for now, changing XMLout($JSONOutput) to XMLout($JSONOutput, NoAttr => 1) gave me the output as elements.

Answer (score 1):

XML::Simple is [horrible module](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33267765/589924). Its own documentation [advises](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Simple#SYNOPSIS) you to avoid it!

XML::Simple is the most complex-to-use XML parser available, and that's assuming it can even do what you want it to do. When it comes to generating XML, it is tragically hopeless

Use [XML::Writer](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Writer) or something.